# Regular expression to allow for number values between 1-3 digits?

Tags: regex

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/$ index.php?gallery_id=$1
```

It allows for any number that is three digits in length. I do not know how to allow for less than three digits as well (or more than three for that matter).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You want to do something along the lines of

```
[0-9]{1,3}
```

There are some excellent examples [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).  Scroll down to nearly the bottom of the page, there are examples of how the various range selections (not the right term for them) work.

Comment: the `{n,m}` construct means "a minimum of n and a maximum of m of the following block" so it reads as "anything 0-9 1 to 3 times"

Comment: Thank-you, that worked perfectly and the link you provided is also very helpful.

Comment: You could have also used (\d{1,3}).

Comment: @jcoggins [Those aren't always the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)