# Regex to allow any occurrence of one symbol in any position of the string?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'd appreciate if someone could help..

I need to allow the occurrence of dash (-) in any position of the string (except the beginning).

My RegEx is:

```
^[+]?[0-9]{3,10}$
```

I want to allow the following possibilities:

```
+7-777-77777
7-7-7-7-7-77
```

etc. so that I could have dash in any place after plus (+) and first digit.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In what situations doesn't your regex work?

Comment: Can you tell us for what purpose?  We might be able to suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead

```
^(?=([^\d]*\d){3,10}[^\d]*$)[+]?\d+(-\d+)*$
 --------------------------
           |
           |->match further only if there are 3 to 10 digits in string
```

This would match string with three to 10 digits optionally having `-` in between the string

---

try it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28?=%28%5B%5E%5Cd%5D%2a%5Cd%29%7B3,10%7D%5B%5E%5Cd%5D%2a%24%29%5B%2b%5D?%5Cd%2b%28-%5Cd%2b%29%2a%24&input=123%0A12345678912%0A1-2-3%0A1--2--3%0A%2b123)

---

If you want optional space in between the strings

```
^(?=([^\d]*\d){3,10}[^\d]*$)[+]?\d+(\s*-\s*\d+)*$
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please also advise how to optionally have the space \s in between the same string? (along with - )

Comment: @GyuzalRakhmayeva a single space or more..also should the space occur anywhere in between the string

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern you're looking for is this:

```
^[+]?[0-9][0-9-]{2,9}$
```

This will match an optional plus, followed by a decimal digit, followed 2 to 9 decimal digits or hyphens.

If you also want to ensure that the string doesn't *end* with a hyphen, simply use this:

```
^[+]?[0-9][0-9-]{1,8}[0-9]$
```

This will match an optional plus, followed by a decimal digit, followed 1 to 8 decimal digits or hyphens, followed by a decimal digit.

Note you can also extend this to all Unicode digits (see [this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/1715579)):

```
^\+?\d[\d-]{2,9}$
```

or

```
^\+?\d[\d-]{1,8}\d$
```

Comment: i guess op wants to match 3 to 10 digits optionally having `-` anywhere

Answer (score 0):

http://rubular.com/r/8eyAolNHlX
In Ruby it should Works:

```
  /\+?(?:\d\-?\d?)+/
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
^[+]?\d(-?\d){2,9}$
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires the input start and end with a digit with optional plus at front

```
^\+?\d[\d-]{,8}\d$
```