# Regex for exactly 6 char, first must be a letter

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

What is the regex that matches these examples(6 characters, first is a letter, others are numbers):

```
u78945 - valid
s56123 - valid
456a12 - invalid
78561d - invalid
1234567 - invalid
```

i don't know if regular expressions are the same for every programming language. I need it for Regular Expression Validator control using VB ASP.NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
^[a-z][0-9]{5}$
```

This will match any Latin letter (lower-case unless using case-insensitive matching) followed by 5 decimal digits.

Note: You could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`, but [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) for an explanation about why they are different.

Comment: Thank you @p.s.w.g I wasn't aware of the unicode characters caught by \d. I'll probably still use it, but it is good to be aware ;)

Comment: @AndyG Both are valid, depending on what exactly you need. If validating user input, I'd prefer `\d` for international support. If really want to ensure that `0-9` are the only valid values, that's probably what you should use.

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-zA-Z]\d{5}
```

If you are searching explicitly from the beginning of the line use ^

```
^[a-zA-Z]\d{5}
```

and append $ for the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a(?i)-z(?i)]\d{5}$
```

The `(?i`) code enables the expression to accept any letter without case-sensitivity. The `\d{5}` looks for a sequence of numbers whose length is exactly 5.