# How to tell if some language's/command's regular expression supports things such as \d \w?

Tags: regex

In some languages or commands (eg: javascript) I can use \d, \w

In others I have to use [0-9], [a-zA-Z]

How to tell when I can use \d, \w?

[A side question: can Notepad++ and grep use them?]

Comment: That entirely depends upon the regex engine.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/1578604).

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: Try it and see. Unless you're writing a program to compare different regex engines sight-unseen, it should take only a couple minutes to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - RTFM for each language/function what kind of RegExp they support, as there are different dialects, at least (I really don't remember all differences, have to read manual each time for new function):

1. [Perl Compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)
2. [Posix](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere)
3. [GNU](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere)

And of course not all languages fully supports any kind of standard, so after reading common manual you have to struggle with peculiarities of particular implementation

Answer (score 1):

Look up a reference for the language you're using the regexes in or try them out; we can't give an exhaustive reference here.

Notepad++ does have regex support, but I've found it to be flaky. It's supposed to support the basic character classes, though. Grep, I'm less familiar with. I'd expect it to, but...try and see.