# Remove text appearing after numbers in Notepad++ using regular expressions

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large text file which contains many timestamps. The timestamps look like this: `2013/11/14 06:52:38AM`.  I need to remove the last two characters (am/pm/AM/PM) from each of these. The problem is that a simple find and replace of "AM" may remove text from other parts of the file (which contains a lot of other text).

I have done a find using the regular expression `(:\d\d[ap]m)`, which in the above example would track down the last bit of the timestamp: `:38AM`. I now need to replace this with `:38`, but I don't know how this is done (allowing for any combination of two digits after the colon).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** What I needed was to replace `(:\d\d)[ap]m` with `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `(:\d\d[ap]m)` into `(:\d\d)[ap]m` and use `$1` not `\1`

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works using `\1`. Is there any advantage to using `$1` instead? Or is it just something that Notepad++ does differently?

Comment: I always used $1 and not \1, I believe $1 is perl way? and \1 is ruby? or python? anyway if both work, cool :) btw, notepad++ officially supports PCRE (Perl), and documentation states ``$n, ${n}, \n
Returns what matched the subexpression numbered n. Negative indices are not alowed.``

Comment: In the case of Notepad++ `\1` and `$1` makes no difference. But in most other cases, like Perl, PHP etc, it does so it's better to get used to the `$` notation. Read why on [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-\1-Instead-of-$1).

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   [0-9]{2}\K[AP]M
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   [leave empty]
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/hY3iJ3).

Note: the use of `[0-9]` is generally better than `\d` ([read why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/2140859)), and avoiding to use a capture group `$1` with the use of `\K` is considered better. It's definitely not important in your case, but it is good to know :)