# Match floats in Ruby with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex, match

I need to extract a float from a string in Ruby, but if I try to extract it with the normal \d I of course don't fetch the digits in front of the ",".

```
"3,25 år -".match((\d+)\s?år\s?-)[1] => # "25"
```

Is there an easy way to fetch the whole number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"3,25 år -".match(/([\d,]+)\s?år\s?-/)[1] => # "3,25"
```

Pay attention that your code also had another error. You were missing the regex delimiters. It should be

```
match(/.../)
```

not

```
match(...)
```

Comment: Thanks @psxls. Also thanks for pointing me to the Scuba Diving proposal. I'm a Scuba Instructor, I've added the proposal to my profile, it may help to advertise it a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the forward slashes `/` around the regular expression.

Apart of that, this will return what you want:

```
"3,25 år -".match(/(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s?år\s?-/)[1] => # "3,25"
```

As a side note, the above will match both positive integers and floats. If you are sure you will always have floats, simplify it like that:

```
"3,25 år -".match(/(\d+,\d+)\s?år\s?-/)[1] => # "3,25"
```

Finally, I would propose you to get used to the `[0-9]` notation for digits instead of `\d`, ready [why here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/2140859), so finally try this:

```
"3,25 år -".match(/([0-9]+,[0-9]+)\s?år\s?-/)[1] => # "3,25"
```

PS. I would suggest you to avoid the `[\d,]+` solutions since this regular expression can match also non-numbers, eg it will match `1,,1` or `1,` or `,1`.