# Regular Expression Repeating Pattern separated by comma

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression of the following:

```
.regex(/^(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})$/)
```

Must be exactly 4 characters
Must contain at least 1 numeric and 1 alpha

Although I rarely do regular expression, this was relatively easy.  I now have a new requirement that I have tried to implement, but cannot get right.

New requirement:  Be able to have a comma separated list of the same type of input as before.  Cannot end with a comma.  Each item must be valid per the rules above (4 characters, at least on numeric, at least one alpha)

```
Valid:  123F,U6Y7,OOO8
Invalid:  Q2R4,
Invalid:  Q2R4,1234
Invalid:  Q2R4,ABCD
Invalid:  Q2R4,N6
```

I very much appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: You can try this site - http://txt2re.com/
It will help you build the expression from scratch.

Answer (score 10):

Some of the other answers are repeating the lookahead assertions.  That's not necessary.

Here's a regular expression that matches a comma-separated sequence of atoms, where each atom is four alphanumeric characters:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:,[A-Z0-9]{4})*$
```

Of course, that's not quite what you want.  You don't want atoms that are all alphabetic.  Here's a negative lookahead assertion that prevents matching such an atom anywhere in the text:

```
(?!.*[A-Z]{4})
```

And you don't want atoms that are all numeric either:

```
(?!.*[0-9]{4})
```

Putting it all together:

```
^(?!.*[A-Z]{4})(?!.*[0-9]{4})[A-Z0-9]{4}(?:,[A-Z0-9]{4})*$
```

Answer (score 3):

This regex should work:

```
^(?:(?![0-9]*,)(?![a-zA-Z]*,)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4},)*(?![0-9]*$)(?![a-zA-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

Or you can shorten `[0-9]` to `\d`. It doesn't really matter, though, since the expanded code can be more readable.

```
^(?:(?!\d*,)(?![a-zA-Z]*,)[a-zA-Z\d]{4},)*(?!\d*$)(?![a-zA-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z\d]{4}$
```

You can see how your regex is transformed to make this regex, when I line it up like below:

```
^
(?:
  (?!\d*,)(?![a-zA-Z]*,)[a-zA-Z\d]{4},
)*
  (?!\d*$)(?![a-zA-Z]*$)[a-zA-Z\d]{4}
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this regex ([regex test](http://regex101.com/r/bE5wR2)):

```
.regex(/^(?:(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})(?:(?:\b\,)(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})*$/)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\b\,)` -> Match with a `,` at the beginning of the string **only** if its preceded by a word boundary
- `(?:(?![0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})` -> Match a string with letter and digits **only** if **dont** have 4 digits ow 4 letters

Comment: you might be able to clean it up with some \w and \S and \D tags

Comment: @ZachLeighton: \w contains `_`, `\S` contains a bunch of space characters that may differ between engines. And it is not nice to introduce imprecision into the regex.

Comment: Actually I think \w and \d are less effective because it match with some characters that isn't in our alphabet. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) to understand what I'm talking about

Comment: \S is any nonwhitespace and you could remove _ from \w

Comment: @ZachLeighton: There is no need to shorten the regex if it doesn't make the regex easier to read.

Comment: If it is a comma separated list, you have to have comma separating `AAA2` from `BBB3` '-'

Comment: I mean it is an invalid case, accepted by your regex. It fails the requirement of 4 characters per item.

Comment: forget, was looking in the old regex

Answer (score 1):

I want to **highlight the advantage of my answer** as comparison to other answers as follows:

- My answer intuitively encodes the requirement "at least one alpha" and "at least one numeric".
  Other answers make use of the fact that considering the universal set of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, which after some thoughts, those two requirements translate into "not all alpha and not all digits".
- In my answer, you can change the universal set to anything you want (even with a comma!), and don't need to change the regex for the other requirements.

My answer:

```
^(?=.{0,3}\d)(?=.{0,3}[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}(,(?=.{0,3}\d)(?=.{0,3}[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/z8duJ2z_dWACj3kq)

Explained as:

```
^
  (?=.{0,3}\d)(?=.{0,3}[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}   # Main part
  (,
    (?=.{0,3}\d)(?=.{0,3}[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}
  )*
$
```

The "main part" matches any four characters composed by alphanumerics (`[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}`), containing at least one digit (`(?=.{0,3}\d)`) and at least one letter (`(?=.{0,3}[a-zA-Z])`). Then just repeat that pattern preceded with a comma.