# Check regex for letters numbers and underscore characters

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to check if a string *Name* contains letters, numbers, and underscore character with
the following code without success, any idea of what I miss here?

var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$^\w+$");

```
        if (regex.IsMatch(Name) )
```

....

in addtion when I tried with the following code, I got a parsing error
 `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.`

```
Var regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]+$");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex should be:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
```

You don't need to escape the underscore. You can also use the Regex.Ignorecase option, which would allow you to use `@"^[a-z0-9_]+$"` just as well.

Comment: Why not just   @"^\w+$"

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Because if there are unicode hanging around, they might match as well. `\w` is not really restricted to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/1578604). This linked question is about `\d`, but `\d` is a subset of the `\w` class, and I'm not gonna mention all the variations of letters.

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't realize the pool of matching characters was so large.  I guess most people mean [a-z0-9] when they write letters and digits, so the unicode should be excluded.  And I didn't realize, until reading that link, that there were unicode digits to also be concerned about.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I didn't know either before seeing that question I linked. But I prefer keeping it strictly to the 'usual' alphabet and numbers unless explicitly mentioned otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$
```

You can match name with length also by this regex

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{m,n}$

Where
m is the start index
n is the end index
```

## [Regex Demo](http://rubular.com/r/xwaXCKn1ut)

Take a look at [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)