# Is there a way to shorten this regex?

Tags: regex

The following regex suits my pattern. But, I am wondering if there is a way to shorten it. I can't use \w because I want only case insensitive English alphabets. Because the pattern repeats I am wondering if I can group it if that is possible.

```
([A-Za-z]{5}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{8}\-[0-9]{6})\.csv
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript regex question I presume?  It's pretty general, but that is still helpful to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten a bit to this:

```
([A-Za-z]{5}(\.[A-Za-z]{3}){3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6})\.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

`\d` instead of `[0-9]` is an obvious way to shorten it a bit:

```
([A-Za-z]{5}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.[A-Za-z]{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{2})\.(\d{8}\-\d{6})\.csv
```

Next, consolidate the repeated pattern that @anubhava pointed out:

```
([A-Za-z]{5}\.([A-Za-z]{3}\.){3}\d{3}\.\d{2})\.(\d{8}\-\d{6})\.csv
```

Setting case insensitivity at the outset will shorten the regex a bit further...

```
(?i)([a-z]{5}\.([a-z]{3}\.){3}\d{3}\.\d{2})\.(\d{8}\-\d{6})\.csv
```

...while also matching `.CSV` (i.e. versus just `.csv`) files, which you may not have considered but typically would be valid.

Finally, there are 4 parentheses that may be extraneous and dispensable:

```
(?i)[a-z]{5}\.([a-z]{3}\.){3}\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{8}\-\d{6}\.csv
```

Comment: `\d` is an obvious thought at first but it doesn't exactly equals `[0-9]`. It includes more characters: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/72478

Comment: @cherouvim: I don't typically run regexes against Unicode input strings, but that is a fair point if Unicode input strings are a concern.

Comment: @cherouvim: It depends on the language. C# matches Unicode digits by default, but Java, JavaScript don't. From Java 7, the `(?U)` flag can be used to make `\d` matches Unicode digits, but that is after using flag.

Comment: These are great points regarding Unicode (and performance) considerations.  Thanks!