# How do I find a particular word followed by a space followed by a number?

Tags: regex

Using regular expressions, how do I find a particular word followed by a space followed by a number?

Example:

`Bug 125`

Where "Bug" is should always be the **first** word found in a line of text followed by a space and then a number and nothing else.

In other words, I don't want to find "Bug 125" as written within some paragraph in the same text file I am parsing.

I haven't tried much because I am terrible at regular expressions.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
^Bug [0-9]+$
```

Where:

- `^` = Starts with
- `[0-9]+` = One ore more digits
- `$` = Ends with this

Comment: +1 Setting "multiline mode" on the regex engine options probably would be a good idea.

Comment: I hate using `\d` as it kinda obfuscates things. I prefer `[0-9]` as it is clear that we are using the numbers 0 to 9. But that's just my personal preference.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper: Someone mentioned on another SO question recently that `[0-9]` is indeed preferable - for a small performance gain but, more importantly, also because `\d` will technically match Unicode characters other than the digits 0-9.  This is something to watch for.

Comment: @ShadowCreeper: Aforementioned mention of `\d`'s looseness - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21950819/1810429](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21950819/1810429).

Comment: @J0e3gan Thanks for the link. This is good to know. And that comment points to a more exhaustive list of unicode digits here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9/16621778#16621778

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
^Bug [0-9]+$
```

- "^"     - begining of the line
- "Bug "  - the word and follow-on space you want to match
- "[0-9]" - a digit 0-9
- "+"     - one or more (digits)
- "$"     - end of the line