# [A-z0-9]+ regexp matching square brackets

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with the following regexp

```
[A-z0-9]+
```

If tested against this string:

```
||a919238[.--a]asd|
```

it returns `a919238[`, including the square bracket.. I tried to input [my test case on regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/lE6cR8/2) to understand what's wrong, but the site regex explanation is not helping, probably I'm not able to see my mistake.

Why is the square bracket included in the result?

Comment: Look at the [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) - which characters are between A and z?

Comment: @georg square bracket! thanks

Comment: Hmm, I never used A-z before, but I guess that's good because of this!  I've always used A-Za-z0-9 to be explicitly clear on the ranges.

Comment: Better than `[a-Z]` :-)

Comment: @Jonny5 yep, i agree. So mine is also also a duplicate of that question. I'm ready to close the question of mine(i refferred) as duplicate but why i reopen this? I didn't say that the question i referred is the canonical question or i'm the first to post answer for this type of question.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Because

```
[A-z0-9]+ 
 ↑ ↑
```

is from `A` to `z`, see the ASCII table, `]` appears between the two characters:

[image]

Comment: Did you use any too? how did you mark squares?

Comment: Huh. The 41/101 - 61/141 symmetry is nice, but this question is a good example of why ASCII having `A-Z`,`a-z` next to each other would be pretty nice. We'd also then have symbols together, so could match e.g. `[@-~]`. Any idea why it was laid out the way it is?

Comment: This is the reason why you frequently see `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-z]`: to exclude all those extra characters.

Comment: @OllieFord IMO it is this way because the earliest computers are scientific equipment and scientists wouldn't be particularly bothered by it.  Someone just defined it as such and it stayed this way.

Comment: @OllieFord you can switch between upper- and lowercase with the fifth bit alone.

Comment: @Quentin That's due to the 'symmetry' I mentioned, but is that really so useful that that's why? I suppose adding 26 is slightly more expensive, but it's surely not that common?

Comment: @OllieFord that's the only thing I thought about, but I can't find any other argument. I don't know further.

Comment: I think the reason is historical, but it's really interesting. @GrijeshChauhan it's simple Gnome editor :)

Comment: @OllieFord just lack 5 letter in the alphabet or 10 too much and hard to change our alphabet for computer scientist only use :-D

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I'm not sure what you mean - I'm only suggesting the ordering in ASCII numbering didn't have to split upper and lower cases, not that the alphabet should be changed!

Comment: @OllieFord reason is that there are 26 letter in alphabet and not a  corresponding power of 2 -1 like 31 or 15 and they fill the gap with other element

Comment: @NeronLeVelu but only benefit of that is changing case with single bit as Quentin said, right?

Comment: @OllieFord right, they took the first avalaible slop that can contain the whole alphabet and use the next one for upper case to have a logic (lower/upper) in a non logic (alphabet is conventionnal) group of element in a power of 2 world.

Comment: @OllieFord The reason of this is because originally only big letters were available at the time, then the special chars `[, \, ], ^, _` were added. And, later, when the `[a-z]` came, they were added after all of that, in order not to break the standards. If the table had to be built nowadays, `[a-z]` would be likely first, then `[A-Z]` etc...

Comment: @ring0 Source? [RFC 20](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc20) 'ASCII Format for Network Interchange' includes both upper- and lower-case. The 5th-bit-flip seems most convincing, but it would be interesting if anyone has something that explicitly says this (or otherwise).

Answer (score 19):

```
A===>64
z===>122
[===>91
```

So it is in between the range you have defined.Use `[A-Za-z0-9]+`

Comment: Great, I was also looking to remove the square bracket from the result, thanks!

Comment: @BeNdErR   If you can allow `_` then you can use `\w` ....

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `\w` and `[A-Za-z_]` are not equivalent in any Unicode-aware regex dialect.

Comment: @Slade  hmm.. you are correct. [a question is also asked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/1673391) at SO in past

Answer (score 8):

You can use `/[a-z0-9]+/i` (the `i` makes it case-insensitive),  or `/[A-Za-z0-9]+/`.