# Get all words from text containing html tags with php regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am currently trying with PHP to get all words from text that contain html tags

My regex has a problem, if a word is finished with an accent ( "é" for example ), my word is not caught.

My regex is

```
$re = '/([^\r\n\t\f>< /]+(?!>))\b/';
$str = 'Non ! Non ! Je ne veux pas d\'un éléphant dans un boa.<br>
<p> Un boa c\'est très dangereux, et un éléphant élévé c\'est très encombrant. Chez moi c\'est tout petit. J\'ai besoin d\'un mouton. Dessine-moi un mouton.
</p>
-Laisse-moi dire mouton... For saints have hands that pilgrims\' hands do touch
```

';

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// but word elevé is not completely match
print_r($matches);
```

but, in my example, the word "élévé" in not match

Please find an example here :
[regex live example](https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/12)

Why does this regular expression not match the last character with accents?

Comment: Please post a code example so we can better help, but you are _probably_ looking for [mb_ereg_match](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php) — by default, PHP’s string functions only operate on ASCII characters.

Comment: Opening your "live example", match 8 is `éléphant` which includes your accented characters.

Comment: sorry, i update my post. the word "elevé" is not match. thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a regex, you could use:

```
<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([A-zÀ-ÿ]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/13)**

Note that character range in the regex character class uses ASCII range, I put the simplest way, but bear in mind that that range contains symbols that you might not want. If you want to support specific characters check the ascii table and use the range you want

Additionally, if you want to capture `c'est` as a single word, then just add the single quote in the character class as this:

```
<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([A-zÀ-ÿ']+)
```

**Edit:** if you check **[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)** comment, you will find a very useful usage of the unicode flag. Quoting his comment, you can use a very easy regex by leverage `u` (unicode) flag like this:

```
<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([\w']+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/14)**

If you want words separated by `-` like `Dessine-moi` to be matched as a single word instead of 2, just add the hyphen to the caracter class like this:

```
<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([\w'-]+)
```

**Edit 2:** since you edited your question a 2nd time and also commented that you don't want the initial hyphen, then you can use this regex:

```
<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([\w']+(?:[\w'-]*))
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/16)**

Comment: Or `[\w\'-]` instead of `[A-zÀ-ÿ']` together with `u (PCRE_UTF8)` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (further no need for capturing group). Also see [why `A-z` can result in unexpected matches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28449959/5527985).

Comment: thx federico !
just a little things, "c'est" is match on 2 part but it must be just one word. its is possible ? ( juste 1 match if ' ) thx

Comment: @bobblebubble, correct, that's why I put the Note about ASCII range, the idea was to show the range feature, I leave to OP to implement whatever range he wants to use.

Comment: @user3257966 I already answered that, and also using `c'est` as the example. Read the answer and at the end you will find the 2nd regex to match `c'est` as a single word

Comment: @bobblebubble, very useful, didn't know that `\w` also matches accented characters in unicode mode. I added that info to the answer. Thanks for the comment

Comment: a last things my friends .. how i can not catch - symbol if this symbol start my word ? like this : -Laisse-moi dire mouton... ( i edit my post )

Comment: @user3257966 I have added the 2nd edit for your comment

Comment: @frederico .. sorry i m so bad with regex , but in this context "For saints have hands that pilgrims' hands do touch, " the word pilgrims is catch with his ' , any solution ? :)

Comment: @user3257966, you can try this `<[^>]+>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\w+(?:[\w'-]*\w+))`. [Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9uC1/17)