# How can I disallow a square bracket in a string when using regex to validate input text

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I want to disallow a string that has square brackets when using test method in regex.

```
 function validateName(name){
    var nameRegex = /^[A-zA-z\s][A-zA-z\s.-]{1,64}$/i;
    console.log('##########Checking validation.........');
    return nameRegex.test(name);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between regex \[A-z\] and \[a-zA-Z\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z), [\[A-z0-9\]+ regexp matching square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449927/a-z0-9-regexp-matching-square-brackets)... It should be [`^[A-Za-z\s][A-Za-z\s.-]{1,64}$`](https://regex101.com/r/sWiQ2i/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex and let me know:

```
/^[^\[\]]*$/
```

EDIT:

```
const regex = /^[^\[\]]*$/;

console.log(regex.test('ok')) // return true
console.log(regex.test('[ok')) // return false
console.log(regex.test('ok]')) // return false
```

Comment: It is not working out.
  function validateName(name){
    var nameRegex = /^[A-zA-z\s^\[\]][A-zA-z\s.-]{1,64}$/i;
    console.log('##########Checking validation.........');
    return nameRegex.test(name);
}

Comment: I just tried and it works perfectly...

Comment: That's cool. How can include it in this expression: /^[A-zA-z\s][A-zA-z\s.-]{1,64}$/i

Comment: Tell me what you want to do with your regex

Comment: I finally got a simpler regex: /^[a-zA-Z\s]/. At first I was using /^[A-zA-z]$/ which included all symbols with char code 91-96 yet I didn't what them to be matched.
Thanks for all efforts.