# ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator Currency Require 2 decimals for validation

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a very standard ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator and I just need the ValidationExpression to make it so 2 decimal places are required!

Good Examples..

```
234234.00
2342342.12
234.11
2.22
3.33
```

Bad Examples

```
3242.1
2342
3.1
.22
```

I tried `/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/` and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? It is a basic regex, actually.

Comment: i tried... i even tried /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/  and i can't get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
^[0-9]+[.][0-9]{2}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iB6xT9/2)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `[.]` - a literal `.`
- `[0-9]{2}` - exactly 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Your regex - `^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$` - matches 0 to 4 digits at the beginning, and then *optionally* there can be a period followed by 0 to 2 digits before the end of string. It looks like a live validation regex to me, but it cannot be used for final validation.

Comment: works... i'm glad you can make it look so simple lol.  Things i read talked about using "d" im not sure why though

Comment: There is always a problem with escaping regex metacharacters. Using character classes (those `[...]`) relieves that pain in many cases.

Comment: I see that there are already 2 answers here that look identical to mine. `^\d+\.\d{2}$` is the same as `^[0-9]+[.][0-9]{2}$` in JavaScript ES5 - BUT not in .NET, where `\d` may match Persian and some other numeric characters. Perhaps, you would like to avoid that. Check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/\d+\.\d{2}$/
```

One or more digits, followed by a single dot and followed just for two other digits at the end of the string.

https://regex101.com/r/lF9uU2/1

Comment: Check [what `\d` may match in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
/^[0-9]+\.?[2]*$/
```

Comment: This regex matches 1 or more digits from the beginning of the string, then 1 or 0 dots, and then 0 or more `2` symbols up to the end. I doubt it is what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the RegEx value of the validator to the following verbatim string in your server-side code:

```
@"^\d+\.\d{2}$"
```

Comment: I tested mine and it gives the expected result for all of your test cases.

Comment: Check [what `\d` may match in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Comment: That's a good point @stribizhev .  If you need to allow Unicode digits, then \d is the way to go.  If you need to allow only 0 to 9, then use [0-9].