# Regex for MasterCard

Tags: c#, .net, regex, credit-card

I found the following regex for credit card type MasterCard

```
public static readonly string CreditMasterCard = @"^(5[1 - 5][0 - 9]{14})$";
```

then I wrote the following code:

```
Regex regexMasterCard = new Regex(CommonLibrary.RegexCreditCardStrings.CreditMasterCard);

if (regexMasterCard.IsMatch(number)) return CommonLibrary.CreditCardType.mastercard;
```

But when I set number='5308171154251187' it's wrong. What is incorrect in regex?

Comment: Remove spaces in the pattern

Comment: Is this intended to replace a check against the Luhn algorithm?

Comment: @Mathemats, no, just client validation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to remove the spaces inside the character classes:

```
^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$
```

Those spaces are always meaningful inside a character class (even if you specify the `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` flag) and in your case they created ranges from space to space, not from 1 to 5 and 0 to 9 digits. Also, there is no need in the outer parentheses, you do not need to capture the whole pattern (you can always refer to the whole match with `$0` backreference or `match.Value`).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e5%5b1-5%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b14%7d%24&i=5308171154251187).

As per @saj comment, you may now use

```
^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XQMBq7/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)` - any of the alternatives:

  - `5[1-5][0-9]{2}` - `5`, a `1` to `5` and any 2 digits (`5100` to `5599`)
  - `222[1-9]` - `2221` to `2229`
  - `22[3-9][0-9]` - `2230` to `2299`
  - `2[3-6][0-9]{2}` - `2`, then `3` to `6` and any 2 digits (`2300` till `2699`)
  - `27[01][0-9]` - `2700` till `2719`
  - `2720`  - `2720`
- `[0-9]{12}` - any 12 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: MasterCard has now started numbers 2221 through 2720. All have 16 digits.So use this regex,^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{2}|222[1-9]|22[3-9][0-9]|2[3-6][0-9]{2}|27[01][0-9]|2720)[0-9]{12}$

Comment: You can probably shorten the regex with replacing all `[0-9]` with `\d` -s.

Comment: @AndresEhrenpreis [I am not sure it is a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).