# Should I use the RegEx for 1 simple test on a single character?

Tags: c#, regex

I am replacing some very old c++ code that is in use at my job with a c# desktop app. 
In the c++ a naming convention was established that included smartcoding (yes, bad, I know but I can't change it) in some persisted object names. In the old code, if a name string begins with a number, the named object is handled with a distinct type of object (0-9 only, no other possibilities such as the Persian digits, & etc. referenced here: [Is \d less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)).  I know there are dozens of ways to determine this and I only have to test the first character but I'm curious what's my better choice between something like this

```
Regex reg = new Regex("[0-9]");
bool bdistinct = reg.IsMatch(objname.Substring(0,1));
```

and something like this

```
char k0 = objname.ToCharArray(0,1)[0];
bool bdistinct = ((k0>='0')&&(k0<='9'));
```

or is there something else obvious and far simpler that I'm not considering?

I don't know if it makes any difference (and I guess that is an underlying question) but I don't use any RegEx references anywhere else in the replacement code (so far) which is all pretty simple stuff (very few namespaces and references in use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` comparison is going to be the fastest way to do this, note that you can access characters directly from a `string` for slightly cleaner code:

```
char k0 = objname[0];
bool bDistinct = k0 >= '0' && k0 <= '9';
```

Comment: Thanks @Bradley. I thought declaring the char variable helped phrase the question better (more analogous to the Regex solution) but you are right it was superfluous. The char comparison being faster is, I believe, the thing that is being voted up and it answers my op question completely.

Comment: Oops. I said " declaring the char variable" and left out " and assigning it explicitly" but when I noticed it was too late to fix it (5 min limit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
char k0 = objname[0];
int x = Int32.Parse(k0);
bool bDistinct = x >= 0 && x <= 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to determine if a character is a digit is to call [Char.IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh(v=vs.110).aspx). In your code, that would be:

```
bool bdistinct = Char.IsDigit(objname[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim. I had never used `IsDigit` (and forgot it existed).  I'm curious now how it compares to `(k0>='0')&&(k0<='9')`.  Does using `IsDigit` imply the analogous question about non-ASCII digits (referenced in my op)? (In other word, is `IsDigit` looking only at 0-9?)

Comment: [Here is the source for the `IsDigit` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,041e77a953545d16)

Comment: @Bill1260231: See the linked documentation for `Char.IsDigit`.