# How to write the regex pattern to get the matched string?

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Am struggling in writing the regular expression pattern for the below string. I used the below pattern to get the matched string. But, i got the error.

Note: The input string may be anyone of the below input string.

```
string input = "IN-7874 - hello";
// or "IN-7874 - Hello"
// "IN-7874 - 1) hello"
// "IN-7874 - 1. hello"
// "IN-7874 - 1)hello"
// "IN-7874 - 1.hello"
string pattern = @"^[A-Z]+\\-^[0-9]\s+\\-\\s+^[A-Z]"; //[any number of capital letters]hyphen[any number of numbers(0-9)]space[hyphen]space[numbers or strings]
var a = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

My output should be in the pattern form of [any number of capital letters]hyphen[any number of numbers(0-9)]space[hyphen]space

Example: {SAM-123 - }// don't consider the curly brace.

Comment: Your `input` var is broken code, escape the quotes inside if these are literal quotes. Also, you must have wanted 1 `^`  at the start of the pattern, others should be removed. Try `^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\s+-\s+[A-Za-z]+`. Or `^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\s+-\s+(?:\d+[.)]\s*)?[A-Za-z]+`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew. Thank you. It worked. Mark this is as an answer.

Comment: The last one, right?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes. The last one worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[A-Z]+-[0-9]+\s+-\s+(?:[0-9]+[.)]\s*)?[A-Za-z]+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Z%5d%2b-%5b0-9%5d%2b%5cs%2b-%5cs%2b(%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%2b%5b.)%5d%5cs*)%3f%5bA-Za-z%5d%2b&i=IN-7874+-+hello%0d%0aIN-7874+-+Hello%0d%0aIN-7874+-+1)+hello%0d%0aIN-7874+-+1.+hello%0d%0aIN-7874+-+1)hello%0d%0aIN-7874+-+1.hello&o=m)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\s+` - see above
- `(?:[0-9]+[.)]\s*)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `[.)]` - a literal `.` or `)`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters

Comment: Note I used `[0-9]` instead of `\d` since [in .NET, `\d` may match more than just `0` to `9` digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9).

Comment: Thank you so much. Clear explanation with perfect solution.