# Regular expression in c# for input like (integer-anything)

Tags: asp.net, regex

```
string strRegexclass = @"^([0-9]+)\-([a-zA-Z])$";
```

I want to make regular expression which accept input like this (1-class). Any integer value before dash(-) and then must have dash then anything after dash.

Comment: Maybe `^[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+$` will do. If you really mean anything, then `^[0-9]+-.*$`

Comment: yes i mean any thing.. ^[0-9]+-.*$ this did my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to only match a string that starts with 1 or more *ASCII* digits, then a hyphen, and then any 0+ chars use:

```
^[0-9]+-.*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B-.*%24&i=12-c%24lass)

Note that [`\d` and `[0-9]` are not equal in .NET regex flavor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code like this:

```
string strRegexclass = @"^\d+-.*$";
```

Or you can use the next code

```
string strRegexclass = @"^\d+-\w*$";
```

if you want to allow only letters after the dash.