# RegEX cannot match in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to find the folder name with special word. My code doesn't work. Would someone tell me how to solve it.
I want the folder name with or without () would be fine. I am not sure how many digit in the blanket. There are example:

```
C:\test\REG33006\2017-03-09
C:\test\REG33006\2017-03-09(1)
C:\test\REG33006\2017-03-09(100)
```

There is my code in vb:

```
 Dim Dir as string="C:\test\REG33006\2017-03-09(1)"
 Dim patt As String ="^C:\\test\REG33006\\2017-03-09\(*\d*\)*$"
 Dim regex As Regex = New Regex(patt)
 Dim match As Match = regex.Match(Dir)
     If match.Success Then
         If Dir.Contains(")") Then
             Dim indexStart As Integer = Dir.IndexOf("(")
               maxNumber = CInt(Dir.Substring(indexStart + 1, Dir.Length -  indexStart))


         End If
     End If
```

Comment: Try with a capturing group - `"^C:\\test\REG33006\\2017-03-09(?:\((\d*)\))?$"` -> `If match.Success Then maxnumber = match.Group(1).Value`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank it is work

Comment: I added an answer with the pattern explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis define a capturing group.
You can use sth like

```
    dim patt as string = "C:\\test\\REG33006\\2017-03-09\((.*)\)"
    if match.success then
         result = match.groups(1).value
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
 Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^C:\\test\\REG33006\\2017-03-09(?:\(([0-9]*)\))?$")
 Dim match As Match = regex.Match(Dir)
 If match.Success Then
     maxnumber  = match.Group(1).Value
 End If
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `C:\\test\\REG33006\\2017-03-09` -  a literal char sequence `C:\test\REG33006\2017-03-09`
- `(?:\(([0-9]*)\))?` - an optional (1 or 0 times) sequence of:

  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `([0-9]*)` - Group 1 (its value is retrieved with `match.Group(1).Value`): zero or more digits
  - `\)` - a `)`
- `$` - end of string,

Comment: Note that [`\d` is different from `[0-9]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970) in .NET regex (by default).