# How to get 1st char from every word with all digit in a sentence?

Tags: c#, regex

I've some `sentences`, those construct with `words` and `digits`. I want to get a `string` that contain `1st char` from every `word`, `all digit` and the word have `all upper case` letters. I've tried using `Regex` but the problem is, it not give `all digit` and `all upper case` letters.

My Regex is in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Z6ZA2R/1).

My solution is in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dowcae).

**CODE:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string> {"Freestyle steel","Freestyle Alloy","Trekking steel uk","Single speed","5 speed","15 speed","3 Speed internal gear with 55 coaster","MTB steel","Junior MTB"};
        foreach(string data in list)
        {
            string regex = @"(\b\w)|(\d+)";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(data, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            string output = "";
            foreach(Match item in matches)
            {
                output += item.Groups[1];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

> ### Sample Input
>
> Freestyle steel
>
> Freestyle Alloy
>
> Trekking steel uk
>
> Single speed
>
> 5 speed
>
> 15 speed
>
> 3 Speed internal gear with 55 coaster
>
> MTB steel
>
> Junior MTB
>
> ### Sample Output
>
> Fs
>
> FA
>
> Tsu
>
> Ss
>
> 5s
>
> 15s
>
> 3Sigw55c
>
> MTBs
>
> JMTB

Comment: Use `var regex = @"\d+|\b\w";` and then `output += item.Value.ToUpper();`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Considering OP's output, he wants to keep lowercase letters as well.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it give all digit but not the word that have all upper case letters.

Comment: You might use [`\d+|\b([A-Z]+|\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/BTBFmx/1/)

Comment: @Jan, it's working. Thanks

Comment: Both solutions (Answers) are working well.

Comment: They are different, see [Jan's regex](https://regex101.com/r/XWxKGK/1) will extract `MTB` from `MTBssss`. Also, my regex will extract any Unicode ALLCAPS words.

Comment: Also, see [the difference between `\d` and `[0-9]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I've checked and found the difference. Input: `MTBsss aaa`, Output: `Ma` in your solution but `MTBa` in @Jan's solution.

Comment: Yes, because I supposed you only need to keep *whole words*. Your test cases do not include this case.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you may use is

```
@"[0-9]+|\b(?:\p{Lu}+\b|\w)"
```

**Details**:

- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?:\p{Lu}+\b|\w)` - 1+ uppercase letters followed with a trailing word boundary (`\p{Lu}+\b`) or  any word char (`\w`).

See [this solution](http://ideone.com/Evtf19):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var regex = @"[0-9]+|\b(?:\p{Lu}+\b|\w)";
        var list = new List<string> {"Freestyle steel","Freestyle Alloy","Trekking steel uk","Single speed","5 speed","15 speed","3 Speed internal gear with 55 coaster","MTB steel","Junior MTB"};
        foreach(var data in list)
        {
            var matches = Regex.Matches(data, regex).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value.ToUpper());
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", matches));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FS
FA
TSU
SS
5S
15S
3SIGW55C
MTBS
JMTB
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
\d+|\b(?:[A-Z]+|\w)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/BTBFmx/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a replacement:

```
string input = "3 Speed internal gear with 55 coaster";
string pattern = @"\B[a-z]+|\W+";
string replacement = "";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

The `\B` *(non word-boundary)* asserts that the letter matched by `[a-z]` is preceded by a word character, and the `\W` matches any non-word characters.

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%5Ba-z%5D%2B%7C%5CW&i=Freestyle%20steel%0D%0A%0D%0AFreestyle%20Alloy%0D%0A%0D%0ATrekking%20steel%20uk%0D%0A%0D%0ASingle%20speed%0D%0A%0D%0A5%20speed%0D%0A%0D%0A15%20speed%0D%0A%0D%0A3%20Speed%20internal%20gear%20with%2055%20coaster%0D%0A%0D%0AMTB%20steel%0D%0A%0D%0AJunior%20MTB)