# Regex to get numbers after a period in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to find the right regex to extract the numbers after the `.` in the string below. E.g, the first line should return and array of `1 1 1 1 1`, the second should return `2 1 0 1 2`. I can't seem to figure the correct regex expression to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
line = 0.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1            // payline 0
line = 0.2, 1.1, 2.0, 3.1, 4.2            // payline 1
```

So far, I have the code below, but it just returns all the the numbers in the sting instead. eg, the first line returns `0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 0` and the second returns `0 2 1 1 2 0 3 1 4 2 1`

```
foreach (var line in Paylines)
{
    int[] lines = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(line.ToString(), @"\d+")
                                     select int.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();

    foreach (var x in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());        
    }
}
```

Comment: Use String.Split?

Comment: Thanks, for the help. I thought about going that route, but wanted to solve it using regex instead

Comment: \.(?<match>\d+?)

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 5):

You may use a lookbehind-based regex solution:

```
@"(?<=\.)\d+"
```

It matches 1+ digits after a dot without placing the dot into a match value.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C.%29%5Cd%2B&i=0.1%2C%201.1%2C%202.1%2C%203.1%2C%204.1).

In C#, you may use

```
var myVals = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?<=\.)\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value))
        .ToList();
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/k1zvMw).

The `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option is passed for the `\d` to only match ASCII digits in the `[0-9]` range and [avoid matching other Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).