# regular expression matches wrong String

Tags: regex

I would like to match String that contains **letters and numbers WITHOUT space**

I tried `^[a-zA-Z+d*]*$` but it matches String that have only letters

This is what it should do :

```
Nope
Nope 2
MatchPlease123
```

If you want to try in live: 
http://rubular.com/r/pFMkk9ATc0

Thank you

Comment: So the numbers are required?   You need to be more explicit in your pattern definition.

Comment: Numbers alone are not allowed oops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cna-zA-Z%5d*%5ba-zA-Z%5d%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e0-9%5cn%5d*%5b0-9%5d%29%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d*%24&i=Nope%0d%0aNope+2%0d%0aMatchPlease123&o=m) (a bit modified since the input is a multiline string).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])` - a positive lookahead requiring that there must be at least one ASCII letter after any 0+ chars other than ASCII letters
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])` - a positive lookahead requiring that there must be at least one ASCII digit after any 0+ chars other than ASCII digits
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - 0+ ASCII letters or digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you, such a long regex for a little verification lol | I will use it in C# (ASP.NET) but thanks for the details, I've never tried Ruby

Comment: In C#, why use Rubular then? It only supports Onigmo regex library.

Comment: @XavierC.: You will also have to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` or use a `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag. I removed all the tips related to Ruby and adjusted to work with ASCII chars only even in .NET regex with default modifiers.

Comment: Wiktor ah damn, I saw it on an old Stackoverflow topic, I thought it was a tool to test regex online! (because in C# I have to recompile for every edit, which is super long for debugging) |Edit : ok thanks for the tips

Comment: @XavierC. There are a lot of regex testers in the Internet. Those that you may use for testing .NET regexes are RegexStorm.net and RegexHero.net. The best free tool for .NET regex is Ultrapico Expresso (IMHO) (no affiliation with the sites or the tool).

Comment: @Rahul: I think you already understand that. You may remove the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I think this simplest one will also be helpful

[**Regex demo**](http://rubular.com/r/kvxQM1MMCm)

**Regex:** `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]+$`

> **1.** `^` start of string.
>
> **2.** `(?=.*\d)` positive look ahead for digit.
>
> **3.** `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` positive look alphabets.
>
> **4.** `[a-zA-Z\d]+` match all `digits` `A-Z` and `a-z`
>
> **5.** `$` end of string.

Comment: It will also match if there are **only** digits. You will need lookahead for both letters and digits as in Wiktor's answer.

Comment: This is almost same as mine. Note that [`\d` in .NET regex matches more than just `[0-9]` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970). Unless you compile the regex with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but i haven't copied for sir believe me.

Comment: @SahilGulati: I understand your understanding evolved with time, so I understand :)

Comment: @SahilGulati: _but i haven't copied_ . It happens more often that solutions are similar or same in Regex. Hence advised not to post same solution if anyone else has posted before.