# Regex to allow only this format 123-456-7890

Tags: regex, regex-negation

i am looking for a regex to accept only this number not any other format.

```
123-456-7890
```

I have tried this but accepting diff formats as well.

```
Regex regexPhoneNumber = new Regex(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$");
```

Comment: What is wrong with `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`?

Comment: It looks like .NET, so `\d` is better avoided.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I didn't know there is an issue with .NET and `\d`s. Could you share?

Comment: @ndn Unlike in Ruby, .NET `\d` [matches all Unicode digits by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Comment: `^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex regexPhoneNumber = new Regex(@"\A[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}\z");
```

It will accept a string that starts with 3 digits, then has `-`, then 3 digits, `-`, and then 4 digits followed with the very end of string position.

**Details**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `[0-9]{3}` -  3 ASCII digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `[0-9]{3}` - 3 digits
- `-` - again a hyphen
- `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits
- `\z` - the very end of the string (no final newline can follow, as is the case with `$` anchor).

Note that in case you want to use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to shorten the pattern, and still match ASCII only digits, pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the Regex object.