# regex pattern number inside brackets (int)

Tags: regex, vb.net

Have a text

> hjgv ygkuy (1) erg erg ewr (2)erg erg erg er. (3)

want to get 1,2,3  and if there is only one  then just 1

i have tried with `(\d)\)`

i get matches but i want the result like

1,2,3

if just one then just that digit  1

http://rubular.com/r/xDP7h7IRn7

Comment: Looks like you just need `\(([0-9])\)` and grab `match.Groups(1).Value`. Do you need to match `(32)`, `(123)`?

Comment: the number can be in 2 or three digits inside the brackets 
i just need that numbers

Comment: It is common practice to accept the correct solution provided first. Moreover, `\d` [matches more than `0-9` digits in .NET regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970). Using non-capturing groups gives you no advantage, but hampers regex execution. Tom's regex is equal to `\((\d+)\)` and is basically the same as mine (but less precise). That is why it is downvoted: it brings no additional value to the already posted solution and is less precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using capturing groups;

```
(?:\()(\d+)(?:\))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxovwS/2)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple `\(([0-9]+)\)` regex that matches any `(` followed with 1 or more digits and then a `)`, while capturing the digits into Group 1.

See a [VB.NET demo](https://ideone.com/zciPp0):

```
Dim res As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("hjgv ygkuy (1) erg erg ewr (12)erg erg erg er. (321)", "\(([0-9]+)\)")
If res.Count() > 0 Then
    For Each m As Match In res
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1).Value)
    Next
End If
```

Output:

```
1
12
321
```

**Pattern details**:

- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1 matching one or more ASCII digits (as `\d` in a .NET regex [may match more than just `0-9`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970))
- `\)` -  a literal `)`.