# Why is the special character not captured in the regex group

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression for capturing positive & negative time offsets.

```
\b(?<sign>[\-\+]?)(?<hours>2[1-3]|[01][0-9]|[1-9]):(?<minutes>[0-5]\d)\b
```

It matches fine but the leading sign doesn't appear in the capture group. Am I formatting it wrong?
You can see the effect here https://regex101.com/r/CQxL8q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the first `\b`. The `\b` [**word boundary**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) does not match between a start of the string/newline and a `-` or `+` (i.e. a non-word char).

You need to move the word boundary after the optional `sign` group:

```
(?<sign>[-+]?)\b(?<hours>2[1-3]|[01][0-9]|[1-9]):(?<minutes>[0-5][0-9])\b
              ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/idz1zx/2).

Now, since the char following the word boundary is a digit (a word char) the word boundary will work correctly failing all matches where the digit is preceded with another word char.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it.

Answer (score 1):

The word boundary anchor (`\b`) matches the transition between a word character (letter, digit or underscore) to a non-word character or vice-versa. There is no such transition in `-13:21`.

The word boundary anchor could stay between the sign and the hours to avoid matching it in expressions that looks similar to a time (`65401:23`) but you cannot prevent it match `654:01:23` or `654-01:23`.

As a side note `[\-\+]` is just a convoluted way to write `[-+]`. `+` does not have any special meaning inside a character class, there is no need to escape it. `-` is a special character inside a character class but not when it is the first or the last character (i.e. `[-` or `-]`).

Another remark: you use both `[0-9]` and `\d` in your `regex`. They denote the same thing<sup>1</sup> but, for readability, it's recommended to stick to only one convention. Since other character classes that contain only digits are used, I would use `[0-9]` and not `\d`.

And some bugs in the regex fragment for hours: `2[1-3]|[01][0-9]|[1-9]` do not match `0` (but it matches `00`) and `20`.

Given all the above corrections and improvements, the `regex` should be:

```
(?<sign>[-+]?)\b(?<hours>2[0-3]|[01][0-9]|[0-9]):(?<minutes>[0-5][0-9])\b
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `\d` is the same as `[0-9]` when the Unicode flag is not set. When Unicode is enabled, `\d` also matches the digits in non-Latin based alphabets.

Comment: Thanks. Some nice tips there

Comment: @paddyb: Just FYI: [`\d` is not always matching the same chars as `[0-9]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970). It is also true if we use the pattern in Python 3, or with a unicode modifier in PHP, Java, Python 2.