# Regex - Trying to write match validation for Swedish Social Number

Tags: c#, regex

So I want the formats `xxxxxx-xxxx` AND `xxxxxxxx-xxxx` to be possible. I've managed to fix the first section before the dash, but the last four digits are troublesome. It does require to match at least 4 characters, but I also want the regex to return false if there's more than 4 characters. How do I do it?

This is how it looks so far:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{6,8}[-|(\s)]{0,1}\d{4}");
```

And this is the results:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^\d{6,8}[-|(\s)]{0,1}\d{4}");

Match m = regex.Match("840204-2344");
Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // Outputs True

Match m = regex.Match("19840204-2344");
Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // Outputs True

Match m = regex.Match("19840204-23");
Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // Outputs false


Match m = regex.Match("19840204-2323423423");
Console.WriteLine(m.Success); // Outputs true, and this is what I don't want
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\d{6,8}` pattern matches 6, 7 or 8 digits, so that will already invalidate your regex pattern. Besdies, `[-|(\s)]{0,1}` matches 1 or 0 `-`, `(`, `)`, `|` or whitespace chars, and will also match strings like `19840204|2323`, `19840204(2323` and `19840204)2323`.

You may use

```
^\d{6}(?:\d{2})?[-\s]?\d{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b6%7d%28%3f%3a%5cd%7b2%7d%29%3f%5b-%5cs%5d%3f%5cd%7b4%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=123456-7890%0d%0a12345600-7890&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{6}` - 6 digits
- `(?:\d{2})?` - optional 2 digits
- `[-\s]?` - 1 or 0 `-` or whitespaces
- `\d{4}` - 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

To make `\d` only match ASCII digits, pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`option. Example:

```
var res = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\d{6}(?:\d{2})?[-\s]?\d{4}$", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

Comment: Yes, this is better actually, although ASCII digits are for american social numbers right?

Comment: @Jesper: ASCII digits are those that you match with `[0-9]`. There are a lot of Unicode digits, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).

Answer (score -1):

You are forgetting the $ at the end:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d{6}|\d{8})-\d{4}$");
```

If you want to match the social security number anywhere in a string, you van also use \b to test for boundaries:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"\b(\d{6}|\d{8})-\d{4}\b");
```

Edit: I corrected the RegEx to fix the problems mentioned in the comments. The commentors are right, of course. In my earlier post I just wanted to explain why the RegEx matched the longer string.

Comment: Note that `\d{6,8}` matches 6, 7 or 8 digits, and that might be too "permissive" for the current requirements.

Comment: Actually, the [`^\d{6,8}[-|(\s)]{0,1}\d{4}$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b6%2c8%7d%5b-%7c%28%5cs%29%5d%7b0%2c1%7d%5cd%7b4%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=19840204%7c2323%0d%0a19840204%282323%0d%0a19840204%292323%0d%0a&o=m) pattern matches strings like `19840204|2323`, `19840204(2323` and `19840204)2323`.