# c# How to exclude a word from Reg Ex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following expressions.

The only difference between them is route (.gif and .html)

```
crystal.ipac.caltech.edu - - [17/Jul/1995:20:00:23 -0400] "GET /facts/faq04.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 27063

crystal.ipac.caltech.edu - - [17/Jul/1995:20:00:23 -0400] "GET /facts/faq04.html HTTP/1.0" 200 27063
```

And this is RegEx which is used for above ones. And it matchs to both of them.

```
"^([^\\>]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" (\\d{3}) (\\d+|-)"
```

But I need to exclude a first string with **.gif** extension. How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Usually such exclusions are implemented using `negative look ahead`.

Comment: Can't you postprocess the matches? Regex are already hard enough to read as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may suit your needs:

```
"^([^\\>]+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] \"(((?!gif).)+?)\" (\\d{3}) (\\d+|-)"
```

Note the `((?!gif).)` ... that's the negative look-around

Comment: Tip: It is more efficient to use `[0-9]` than it is to use `\d` . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738