# Regex: Word bounary before plus-sign

Tags: c#, .net, regex, phone-number, word-boundary

I'm working with C# and want to parse phone numbers from a string. I live in Switzerland, phone numbers can either have 10 digits like following pattern:
`000 000 00 00` or can start with a `+41`: `+41 00 000 00 00`. I've written following regular expression:

`var phone = new Regex(@"\b(\+41\s\d{2}|\d{3})\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\b");`

This works perfectly fine with the first example, but the one with the "+41" doesn't match. I'm pretty sure there's a problem with the word boundary `\b` and the following `+`. When I remove the `\b` at the start it finds a match with the `+41`-example. My code:

```
    var phone = new Regex(@"\b(\+41\s\d{2}|\d{3})\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\b");

    var text = @"My first phonenumber is: +41 00 000 00 00. My second one is:
    000 000 00 00. End.";

    var phoneMatches = phone.Matches(text);
    foreach(var match in phoneMatches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Output: `000 000 00 00`.

Output without `\b`:

`+41 00 000 00 00
000 000 00 00`

Any solutions?

Comment: Do not use `\b` if the next  expected char can be a non-word char. Use `(?<!\w)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked, thank you. I've never seen `(?` and `<!` in regex... could you explain what those mean? I can't find any reference on the web .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `(?<!\w)` [**positive lookbehind**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of the first `\b`. Since the next expected character can be a non-word char, the word boundary may fail the match, and `(?<!\w)` will only fail the match once there is a word char before the next expected char.

Use

```
var phone = new Regex(@"(?<!\w)(\+41\s\d{2}|\d{3})\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\b");
                        ^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `(?<!\w)` - fail the match if there is a word char immediately to the left of the current location
- `(\+41\s\d{2}|\d{3})` - `+41`, a whitespace and 2 digits, or 3 digits
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary (this one will work since the previous expected char is a digit).

NOTE: To only match ASCII digits, you might want to replace `\d` with `[0-9]` (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970)).

Answer (score -1):

Try this [one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%2B%5Cb41%5Cs%5Cd%7B2%7D%7C%5Cb%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%5Cs%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5Cs%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cs%3F%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cb&i=My%20first%20phonenumber%20is%3A%20%2B41%2000%20000%2000%2000.%20My%20second%20one%20is%3A%20000%20000%2000%2000.%20End.&o=i):

```
(\+\b41\s\d{2}|\b\d{3})\s?\d{3}\s?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\b
```

move the boundary separator inside the () block and place + to precede the word boundary separator.