# php preg_match mismatch

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to know why `preg_match('/(?<=\s)[^,]+(?=\s)/',$data,$matches);`
 matches "List Processes 8989" in the string "20180513 List Processes 8989". The regex I am using should not match numeric characters. What is wrong?

Comment: So what should it match?

Comment: @revo It should match "List Processes" only.

Comment: What makes you think it shouldn't match numeric characters? What part of your regex excludes numeric characters? The `[^,]` basically means: _Any_ characters _except_ `,`.

Comment: Please be clear about the input and desired output.

Comment: If you expect  "List Processes" only then it means there is an space at the end where digits end.

Comment: @ArtūrasKalandarišvili For your given case: "`20180513 List Processes 8989`", the regular expression above [actually doesn't match the digits](https://regex101.com/r/jZ3hqJ/1/), but that's because there's no space after the digit in the given string.

Comment: I encourage you to `var_dump($data)` and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^,]` basically means *any* character *except* `,`. If you want to exclude numeric characters as well, you can replace it with `[^,0-9]`, or better `[^,\d]`, so your regex would look like this:

```
(?<=\s)[^,\d]+(?=\s)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/hJtGgw/1).

I'm assuming the input string in your question is only part of the actual input string you're using because the regex you provided [won't match](https://regex101.com/r/YFUZja/1) the numbers at the end [unless they're followed by a whitespace](https://regex101.com/r/YFUZja/2).

---

### References:

- [Negated Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- [Difference between `[0-9]` and `\d`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/4934172).