# (Regular Expression) To check start with specified text and next numeric

Tags: c#, regex

I'd like to check start with "Text" and next is numeric.
I want this with Regex but can't make it well.

below is example and I only want to get
"Test2018.txt", "Test2019.txt"

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>() {"Test2018.txt", "Test2019.txt", "TestEvent2018.txt", "TestEvent2019.txt"};
fileNames.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p, "Test^[0-9]+*") == true);
```

Comment: `^` matches the start of the string. Check whether the start of the string is before or after `Test` and move the `^` accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` matches the start of the string, so it doesn’t make sense for it to go in the middle of your pattern. I think you also meant `.*` by `*`, but there’s no need to check the rest of the string when checking for `IsMatch` without an ending anchor. (That means `[0-9]+` can also become `[0-9]`.)

No need to use `== true` on booleans, either.

```
fileNames.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p, "^Test[0-9]"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanation make me understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this Regex:

```regex
^Test[0-9]+\.txt$
```

Where

1. `^` denotes the start of the line.
2. `Test` matches the literal text.
3. `[0-9]` matches any numeric digit 0-9.
4. `+` means at least once.
5. `\.` matches the period.
6. `txt` matches the literal text.
7. `$` denotes the end of the line.

And in C#:

```
var matchingFiles = fileNames.Where(p => Regex.IsMatch(p, @"^Test[0-9]+\.txt$"));
```

Comment: `\d` matches all Unicode digits in .NET regular expressions, not just 0–9. `{1,}` is equivalent to `+`. You can use a verbatim string literal `@"…"` to avoid doubled backslashes. `$` optionally matches a newline before the end of the string; use `\z` to match only the end of the string.

Comment: @Ry- Yeah, good call on the `\d` in particular, seems it's [faster like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) too.