# Regex with form As123456-89

Tags: c#, regex

I need regex for the following text validation:

must start with two alpabetic characters, six digits, minus and two digits represent the year, for example:  Ew142356-19

I have tried:

```
 Console.WriteLine(new Regex("[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{6}[\\-]{1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}").IsMatch("Be123456-19"));
```

but it prins `False`

Comment: You swapped `[0-9]` and `[a-zA-Z]` patterns. Besides, you need to use anchors, `^` and `$`. Use `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}$`. See https://ideone.com/q2V40C

Comment: `^[A-Z][a-z][0-9]{6}\-[0-9]{2}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/CKImhM/2/) one:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{6}-[1-9]\d$
```

Notes:

There is no need to do something like `[1-9]{1}`. `[1-9]` already means that this is one element.

Use Anchors: `^` means the start of the string and `$` means the end of it. If you dont use them you could match something `aBe123456-19`

`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`

There is no need to create a set for the `-` sign

Comment: [\d is less efficient than \[0-9\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9)

Comment: @JohnyL Thanks. Dont knew about it.