# Regular expressions to match these pdf file names

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am looking for a regular expression to match the fileNamePattern.
Files are pdf can have these names: 8 alphanumeric chars, `-`, 4 alphanumeric chars, `-`, 4 alphanumeric chars, `-`, 4 alphanumeric chars, `-`, 12 alphanumeric chars + `.pdf`.

Examples:

```
5b7f991f-0726-4dd5-856e-7cea820f02c5.pdf
138bcee6-db7f-47a7-97bf-69c0b3989698.pdf
e988315b-ade7-48e5-9733-35bb59a3c28d.pdf
```

I am using

```
^[A-Z][0-9]{8}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{12}[.]pdf
```

However, I am not sure it is correct as I get no matches.

Comment: Please share the regex pattern you tried.

Comment: ^[A-Z][0-9]{8}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{4}[-][A-Z][0-9]{12}[.]pdf

Comment: Not sure if it is correct . I am bit confused at .pdf

Comment: Is there any way to test this pattern

Comment: Do not use `\w`, it also [matches underscores and a lot of other chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WordCharacter) in .NET. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989965/3832970) with all the explanations and exact solution. [`\d` also matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738) a lot of chars you do not expect.

Comment: BTW, you may use http://regex101.com (to manually create) and http://regexstorm.net/tester (to see if they work in .NET) to test regexps.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only match uppercase letters in your regex, and when you use `[A-Z][0-9]{4}` you do not match four alphanumeric chars, you match a letter followed with 4 digits.

So, you need to *merge* `[A-Z][0-9]` into single character classes `[A-Z0-9]` and then use a case insensitive flag.

Also, you need to use `$` at the end of the regex to make the pattern match the entire string.

Use

```
^[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}[.]pdf$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHS0pg/1)

In C#,

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}[.]pdf$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that case insensitivity can be set with an inline modifier `(?i)`:

```
var pattern = @"(?i)^[A-Z0-9]{8}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{4}-[A-Z0-9]{12}[.]pdf$";
// check if the string matches the pattern
if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern) 
{
    // The string matches...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Regex r = new Regex(@"^\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}\.pdf$");`

If you explicitly don't want underscores, you can use:

`^[a-zA-Z\d]{8}-[a-zA-Z\d]{4}-[a-zA-Z\d]{4}-[a-zA-Z\d]{4}-[a-zA-Z\d]{12}\.pdf$`

Regex is case-sensitive (unless you specify it to ignore case using `RegexOptions`.
Right now the main issue is that your regex is saying to match a letter then match `n` digits instead of matching `n` alphanumeric characters.

With setting the case insensitive flag, your regex can simplify to:

`^[A-Z\d]{8}-[A-Z\d]{4}-[A-Z\d]{4}-[A-Z\d]{4}-[A-Z\d]{12}\.pdf$`

Answer (score 0):

This should work
/(\w{8})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{4})-(\w{12})(.pdf)/i

I tried it at here at [RegEx Testing](https://www.regextester.com/)

\w = alphanmumeric 
{n} = times the sign should appear

gi = are flags:  "i" = case insensitive.

Comment: In C#, regex patterns are not defined with flags like this, `g` modifier is not supported, regex literal notation is not used.