# Validate user input using C# RegularExpressions

Tags: c#, regex

How to Validate numerical input, max length limited 3 and should not start with zero characters (010, 001 should invalidate). I used C# `regex.IsMatch()` with following regex `([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])*`. But it validating inputs start with zeros. How to resolve this..?

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] with a list of input?

Comment: What do you think the asterisk `*` is doing there in your Regex? Also, if your regex should match from the beginning of the string/line, anchor the regex at the start of the string by  using the `^` anchor as first character in your regex.

Comment: Try this => `bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("100", @"^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$");`

Comment: The input numerical, max length 3, should not start with zeros like 010, 001, 05 `private bool Validate(string str)
        {
            bool isValid = true;
            Regex rx = new Regex("^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$*");
            isValid = rx.IsMatch(str);
            return isValid;
        }`

Comment: @KasunAmarasinghe Can you add that code to the question?

Answer (score 4):

You can omit the alternations by repeating a character class 0 - 2 times and you should use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[1-9]` Match a digit 1-9
- `[0-9]{0,2}` Match 0, 1 or 2 times a digit 0-9
- `$` Assert end of the string

**Usage:**

```
bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch("100", @"^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$");
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQ6vSX/1)

Comment: @elgonzo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9

Comment: @elgonzo Try with `๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑-௫௬௭௮`

Comment: Dang! You guys got me. You are correct. It totally escaped me that there are numeric characters other than 0...9 in different languages. Doh! What a massive brainfart ;-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I planed to add my answer but later I think its better to add it to your, if you found well then keep it or otherwise rollback to your version :)

Answer (score 1):

Regex are great sure. Note that you could achieve this easily without any regex:

```
static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)
        && input.Length < 3 && !input.StartsWith("0") && input.All(char.IsDigit); 
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J9fBG5)

Answer (score 1):

I'd be more specific with this one:

```
^((?!(0))[0-9]{0,3})$
```

Explanations:

- 1st one is not 0 & i want maximum 3 digits between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 1):

`[1-9][0-9]{2}$`

This would work as per your requirement. testes on regex buddy with following test cases

1. 001 Fail
2. 1000000 Fail
3. 900 Pass
4. 010 fail

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$` it won't allow starting with zero