# Regular Expression: first character alphabet second onward numeric

Tags: c#, regex

This is my string, which always starts with a alphabet followed by 3 digits, then `-` (hyphen), followed by 3 digits, then alphabet, then 4 digits

```
I123-123S1234N1234
```

I have come up with a regular expression, which seems to be very long! How can I write a better expression for this?

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z].........goes on
```

**Note**

- Shall support case insensitive
- Hyphen, `S` and `N` always constant

Comment: If it's always that fixed format, I think I would split it up using substring rather than regex.

Comment: @HansKilian  Is Regex expensive operation?

Comment: Substring is just easier to code and read, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var testString = "I123-123S1234N1234";
var pattern = @"[A-Za-z]\d{3}-\d{3}[sS]\d{4}[nN]\d{4}";
var isMatch = Regex.Match(testString, pattern).Success;
```

Pattern used: `[A-Za-z]\d{3}-\d{3}[sS]\d{4}[nN]\d{4}`

Explanation:

`[A-Za-z]` - match any letter

`\d{3}` - match three digits

`[sS]` - match `S` or `s` literally

`\d{4}` - match four digits

`[nN]` - match `N` or `n` literally

`\d{4}` - match four digits

Comment: will mark as answer! But it shall support for small letters too! [a-z]

Comment: There is a regex option that makes it case insensitive, thus making it more simple.

Comment: @bradbury9 Yes, you are right, but I prefer using flags only when needed badly

Comment: Is there a validation that can be performed to make sure the alphabetical values are not repeated? [sS]

var testString = "I123-123Sssss1234N1234";

in my validation if I have multiples of the character s repeating the regex still evaluates to true. I would want it to fail

Answer (score 3):

First use the case-insensitive flag, and then when repeating tokens, use `{<number of times to repeat>`}` instead of repeating yourself:

```
(?i)[a-z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}[a-z][0-9]{4}
```

If you want to match the trailing `N1234` as well, then put the final `[a-z][0-9]{4}` in a group, and repeat it twice:

```
(?i)[a-z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}(?:[a-z][0-9]{4}){2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/5ra1eU/1

If the S and N are constant, then don't use character sets to match them, just match the plain characters:

```
(?i)[a-z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}S[0-9]{4}N[0-9]{4}
```

https://regex101.com/r/5ra1eU/2

Comment: \d is also a lot shorter than [0-9]

Comment: @fubo It does with case insensitive flag. Which he mentions to use.

Comment: what is (?i) here

Comment: @bdebaere Better to avoid `\d` when you don't *want* to possibly match [other numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) - it's nice to be as specific as possible

Comment: @kudlatiger `(?i)` is the case-insensitive flag

Comment: Hyphen, R and N always constant. it won't change at those positions

Comment: @kudlatiger Look at the regex101 link - it seems to work just fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191496/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure to have capital letter and S and N constant:

```
[A-Z]\d{3}-\d{3}S\d{4}N\d{4}
```

`[A-Z]` - match any uppercase letter

`\d{3}` - match 3 digits

`S` - match S literally

`\d{4}` - match 4 digits

`N` - match N literally

`\d{4}` - match 4 digits

if you want upper and lower case:

```
[a-zA-Z]\d{3}-\d{3}[Ss]\d{4}[Nn]\d{4}
```

or

```
(?i)[a-z]\d{3}-\d{3}s\d{4}n\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{4}
```