# How can I use regex to get 1 or 2 characters after a specific character?

Tags: regex

How can I use regex to get 1 or 2 characters after a specific character `-`?

For example:

```
33225566-69   => 69
33225544-5    => 5
```

But I don't want more than 3 characters:

```
33226655-678  =>  Do not select
```

Lookbehind is not supported in some browsers.
I want the regex command without lookbehind.

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript?

Comment: For your samples like this would be sufficient: [`\b-(\d\d?)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/dezvoC/1). A word boundary followed by a hyphen, capture 1 or 2 digits, followed by another word boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just match the `-`, then capture 2 digits, negative lookahead for another digit, and extract the captured group, if it exists. In Javascript, for example:

```js
['33225566-69', '33225544-5', '33226655-678'].forEach((str) => {
  const match = str.match(/-(\d{1,2})(?!\d)/);
  console.log(
    match
    ? match[1]
    : 'No Match'
  );
});
```

If the part with the `-` and the numbers are always at the end of the string, then use `$` instead of the lookahead:

```
-(\d{1,2})$
```

Comment: `[0-9]` could also be written as `\d`.

Comment: You can, but `\d` is slower and can match other odd digit-like characters as well (which are *not* `[0-9]`), so unless those are specified as required, I prefer using `[0-9]`

Comment: `\d` is exactly equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're right, thanks. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) a while ago and remembered that a similar problem resulted from `\d` in Python so I had been thinking what `\d` meant was universal, but it's not!

Comment: Yeah, this depends a lot on the regex implementation. In JS and vim `\d` simply means `[0-9]`, in other languages it matches any Unicode digit, and in Perl it can do either (the `/a` flag restricts it to ASCII digits).

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to (-) choose. only number selected.

Comment: @ElhamAM What do you mean by `But I do not want to (-) choose`? I don't understand. Javascript doesn't have anything like `\K` unfortunately, so you *have* to match the `-` (since you said you didn't want to use lookbehind)

Comment: The output of your regex is  "-69" ,  but I want  "69"

Comment: @ElhamAM Press "Run code snippet", and you'll see that it works as desired - you just need to extract the captured group when there's a match, and you'll get the digits.