# How to validate a user's input being in format (1-XXX-XXXX)

Tags: javascript

i'm running into an issue where i'm struggling on the logic behind parsing for 1-XXX-XXXX of a users response, where XXX are integer values.

Comment: Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: I've attempted a bit of regex, but i'm not well versed at it whatsoever. I am able to do XXX-XXXX in regex

Comment: If you've tried a regex solution already, consider adding your existing code into your question. By showing us what you've tried so far, we can point out how to change what you already have to make it work. StackOverflow isn't a free coding service--we're (usually) not going to write your code for you, but we will almost certainly help you fix your existing code.

Comment: Hint: "X" translates to `\d` in regular expression terms.

Comment: Can you post the regex where you did the validation of XXX-XXXX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex match should get you what you're looking for

```js
let regex = /1-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
let candidateValue = getMeSomeValue();

const isValid = (candidateValue || "").match( /^1-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/ );
```

Add `\s` following the `^` and before the `$` if you want to play nice and ignore leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Regex not quite there. Looks like `{}` and `[]` got switched up.

Comment: And he's forgetting three digits

Comment: there's a `d` typo too, I'd go with `/^1-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(candidateValue.trim())` and call it a day

Comment: `\d` covers things other than ASCII `0-9`. It matches the *entire* Unicode General Category `Nd`. Any decimal digit across any language. Here's the set of characters it matches: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm — and see this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9, for why you might want to prefer `[0-9]` over `\d` (unless you intend to accept things like Arabic, Bengali or Lao digits).