# How to get the digits before some particular word using regex in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

We will use below regex to get the digits before the words.

Example :

> 838123 someWord 8 someWord 12 someWord

`(\d+)\s*someWord`

But sometimes anything will come between Number and word.Please see the below example line.

Ex:

> 43434 of someword 12 anything someword 2323 new someword

How to get the exact digit before that word using regex?

Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: It looks like the existing posts answer your question. Please let the answerers and future readers know if you find the answers useful (Take a [tour]). Otherwise please provide more details about what you are looking for and why the answers are not suit your case.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking...

Answer (score 14):

Do this:

`(\d+)[^\d]+some[wW]ord`

You need to accept anything other than digits themselves.
Also I considered both `w` and `W` since your examples contained both.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJbVjw/5)

Comment: Are you looking for a different answer?

Comment: @RezaAghaei maybe

Comment: What are the problems with the current answer that you provided? What improvements are you looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei That fact that OP hasn't accepted any answer yet makes me think if I missed a corner case or something. Alternate approaches to solve it are also welcome.

Comment: @CinCout-ReinstateMonica Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317088/how-to-get-the-digits-before-some-particular-word-using-regex-in-c/59482240#59482240) for a possible missed edge case (not sure if this is relevant to the OP).

Answer (score 4):

Presuming that "anything" does not include digits, you could use this regex:

```
(\d+)[^\d]+someWord
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LW3nM0/2)

Answer (score 3):

One possible "missed corner case" from CinCout's answer is if the match for `someWord` must be exact, e.g. if `notsomeWord` and `someWordNotThis` shouldn't be matched.

The following extension to that regular expression provides a way to address this:

`(\d+)[^\d]*[^\w]some[wW]ord[^\w]`

**Explanation:** The `[^\w]` before or after the matcher for `someWord` look for a ["non-word character"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) before and after it - an end of the line also counts here. This could of course be made more complex/specific, depending on the exact requirements.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJbVjw/6)

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
(\d+)\s?([^\d]*)

(\d+)    - get the digits
\s?      - discard a possible space
([^\d]*) - get all chars that are not digits
```

You can see the test [here](https://regex101.com/r/rVetVv/1)

Answer (score 3):

first separated the `some[wW]ord`, `number` and `space` with a pattern, then execute the second pattern on it

```
 var pattern = @"\b(some[wW]ord|[\d]|\s)*\b";
 var rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 var sentence = "43434 of someword 12 anything someword 2323 new someword";
 var result = string.Empty;
 foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(sentence)){
     result += match.Value;
}
//output => result: 43434 someword 12 someword 2323 someword

 var patternOnCorrectSentence = @"\b(\d+)\s*some[wW]ord*\b";
 var rgxOnCorrectSentence = new Regex(patternOnCorrectSentence);

 var resultOnCorrectSentence = new List<string>();
 foreach (Match match in rgxOnCorrectSentence.Matches(result)){
     resultOnCorrectSentence.Add(match.Value);
 }
 resultOnCorrectSentence.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

 Console.ReadKey();
```

When the first pattern is executed, the sentence will be as desired

> 43434 of someword 12 anything someword 2323 new someword

change:

> 43434 someword 12 someword  2323 someword

Answer (score 2):

But sometimes anything will come between Number and word.Please see the below example line.

Ex:

> 43434 of someword 12 anything someword 2323 new someword

try this

> (\d+)(.*?)someword

Explained

> \d+ - numbers
>
> .*? - anything after numbers but minimum occurrence.
>
> someword - exact match of somewhat

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pmbi11/1)

Answer (score 2):

Using `\s*` will only match 0 or more whitespace characters.

You could use `\D+` but it will also match newlines as it matches any char except a digit.

If you want to match the digits on the same line, you can add not matching a newline to a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\d\r\n]`

In your example, you use `\d`, but if you only want to match 1 or more [digits 0-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) you could use a character class `[0-9]+`

To prevent the digits and the word being part of a larger word you could make use of word boundaries `\b`

If you want to match the word in a case insensitive manner, you could use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` or an inline modifier `(?i)`

```
(?i)\b([0-9]+)\b[^\d\r\n]*\bsomeword\b
```

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3fi%29%5cb%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5cb%5b%5e%5cd%5cr%5cn%5d*%5cbsomeword%5cb&i=838123+someWord+8+someWord+12+someWord%0d%0a43434+of+someword+12+anything+someword+2323+new+someword%0d%0a%db%b1%db%b2%db%b3%db%b4%db%b5%db%b6%db%b7%db%b8%db%b9+someWord)

Answer (score 2):

Use Named Match Captures (To get data use `mtch.Groups["Value"].Value`... etc) to extract the information as needed.

```
(?<Value>\d+)     -- Get the digits
(?<Other>.+?)     -- Capture all text, but minimal (greedy) capture
(?<Key>someword)  -- til the keyword here.
```

When the above is run (*with `IgnorePatternWhiteSpace` otherwise remove the comments and join the pattern to run it such as `(?<Value>\d+)(?<Other>.+?)(?<Key>someword)` with no regex options*) it gets the data for each Data/Key pairs and organizes each in a single match.

**Result**

Here is the result (for your second example) which are all contained in individual matches and their groups and captures provide in each match:

```
Match #0
              [0]:  43434˽of˽someword
  ["Value"] → [1]:  43434
      →1 Captures:  43434
  ["Other"] → [2]:  ˽of˽
      →2 Captures:  ˽of˽
    ["Key"] → [3]:  someword
      →3 Captures:  someword
Match #1
              [0]:  12˽anything˽someword
  ["Value"] → [1]:  12
      →1 Captures:  12
  ["Other"] → [2]:  ˽anything˽
      →2 Captures:  ˽anything˽
    ["Key"] → [3]:  someword
      →3 Captures:  someword
Match #2
              [0]:  2323˽new˽someword
  ["Value"] → [1]:  2323
      →1 Captures:  2323
  ["Other"] → [2]:  ˽new˽
      →2 Captures:  ˽new˽
    ["Key"] → [3]:  someword
  →3 Captures:  someword
```

Visually here is what is matched:

[image]