# Regex which allow only characters and numbers with an optimal

Tags: regex, c++11

I want create a regex with an optimized way that will check 2 characters range from A-Z,a-z and 3 digits,
I tried with below regex

`^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{3}$`

but i am not sure the regex is optimized or not ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is the minimal (and optimal) regexp for your requirement. You should not worry about "optimality" of regular expressions in most cases; the main point to be careful about is repeating the repeats (read up on "catastrophic backtracking" if really interested). Note that it not only match `US202`, but also `PLATYPUS2020 FOR MAYOR`. If you want to avoid this, you need to use the start/end anchors (`^`, `$`).

Comment: @Amadan sorry i forgot put start and end of the regex..
but my requirement is to the regex which check the result in milliseconds,for that using this can i achieve?

Comment: Depending on how much data you have to process, don't worry, the difference is generaly less than `1%` for `10000` values and `\d` better than `[0-9]` for `1 000 000` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is optimal. May one thing to do could be replace \d with [0-9].
your could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) for info. \d matches not only 0-9, it matches all digit, also arabic, persian, etc. Though is less performant. If you want to figure out how good is you regex eprforming use [this website](https://regex101.com/r/hqAPM3/1). You could roughly estimate what would be the performance by viewing the "steps" and also debugging the regex. But your example is extreme simple, performance is not a question you should bother is such example. In the most cases of regex you should not bother at all. There could be thoughts about this, but you would need a comlex set of data with complex pattern requeriments, to this be meaninful. A good rule of thumb for a performant regex is - be as specific as you can, which you regex is, if you have no more info about your dataset.

Comment: Thanks,its correct \d it will take ASCII range but i tried with [0-9],i didn't see that much big difference in performance with \d.

Comment: Thats because - it really does not matter for the simplicity of your case.;)

Comment: I you have performance issues, you probably need to search elsewhere, not in your regex

Comment: "pretty optimal"?  Hmmm.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is just my weird way to express my knowledge.)

Comment: That's not true for all language, for example I've done a Perl Benchmark over an array of random values integer and letters, the difference is less than `1%`