# Regex for selecting number pattern from string

Tags: c#, regex

Not able to figured it out what's wrong with my regex. I'm trying to find following pattern from my string with the use of regex.

```
1231231234
123.123.1234
123-123-1234
123 123 1234
```

Here is my regex pattern:

```
\b((\d{3}[ .-]?){2}(\d{4}))\b
```

It detect incorrect result and the output i get it with the regex is like below. My aim is to not detect the highlighted once.

[image: image1]

What i tried so far but that is also not worked for me.
[image: image2]

Anyone has idea how can i get this out?

Comment: @41686d6564 No my only requirement is the first snapshot the highlighted one should not detect by regex. Thanks

Comment: Then, maybe use `(?<!\.)` instead of `[^.]`.

Comment: If you use your regex in C# code, you are using the .NET regex library, and regex101 does not support this library. Test the patterns for validity at .NET compliant regex testers, regexhero.net or regexstorm.net

Comment: Did any answer below help you?

Comment: Thanks to both yes i tested it and it's working. Learn something new with regex. I'll test with some more data later today.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to prevent the matched text from being preceded by a dot, you can achieve that by simply using a negative Lookbehind (i.e., `(?<!\.)`) instead of the negated character class. You may also add a negative lookahead at the end to prevent the match from being *followed* by a dot:

```regex
\b(?<!\.)((\d{3}[ .-]?){2}(\d{4}))(?!\.)\b
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4PQ8I/1)**.

Note, however, that this (as well as your original pattern) will match numbers separated by different characters (e.g., "123.123-1234"). If you'd like to prevent that, you may use something like:

```regex
\b(?<!\.)\d{3}([ .-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}(?!\.)\b
```

..and add additional capturing groups as you see fit.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JTxu5/1)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
(?<!\d\.?)\d{3}([ .-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}(?!\.?\d)
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%5C.%3F%29%5Cd%7B3%7D%28%5B%20.-%5D%3F%29%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C1%5Cd%7B4%7D%28%3F!%5C.%3F%5Cd%29&i=text.1231231234%0D%0A1231231234%0D%0A123.123.1234%0D%0A123-123-1234%0D%0A123%20123%201234%0D%0A%0D%0A123.1231231234%0D%0A1231231234.123%0D%0A123.123-1234%0D%0A123%20123.1234%0D%0A123123.1234). If you need to make it work at the regex101, choose the JavaScript flavor that now supports variable width lookbehinds, or simply replace the first lookbehind with `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)`:

```js
(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d{3}([ .-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}(?!\.?\d)
```

C# snippet:

```cs
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\d\.?)\d{3}([ .-]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}(?!\.?\d)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Since [`\d` in .NET matches any Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9), you might consider compiling the regex with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

**Pattern details**

- `(?<!\d\.?)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with a digit or digit and a dot
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `([ .-]?)` - Group 1: space, dot or hyphen
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `\d{4}` -  four digits
- `(?!\.?\d)` - a location in string that is not immediately followed with dot or dot and digit.