# Regular expression pattern in c#

Tags: regex

I need to validate the following string

case 1: 123E

The first three are numeric and then the alphabet.

I have created the following pattern

```
var pattern = @"^[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}"
```

Is this correct?

Comment: No. `[0-9]{2}` compares for 2 digits, not 3.

Comment: Almost there. `^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]$` should do. Where `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`.

Comment: var pattern = "^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]$", i am getting compilation error

Comment: @tyu, I replied in an answer with a working `.Net` example.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work: `^[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$`
You put `{2}` for numbers but in your case there are 3 of them so I wrote `{3}` instead.
You don't need to write `{1}` because `[a-zA-Z]` is enough to find exacly one letter.
I also added endline tag `$` to ensure that there are no more symbols after letter.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, as per my comment you can use:

```
^\d{3}[a-zA-Z]$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FASjLl/1)

- `^`  - Start string anchor.
- `\d{3}` - Three digits where `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`<sub>1</sub>
- `[a-zA-Z]` - A single alpha char.
- `$` - End string anchor.

---

See a working `.Net` example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E45D2S)

<sub>1: This would only be the case if the `ECMAScript` flag is enabled. Otherwise `\d` is matching non-ascii digits as per [this](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/matching-digits-in-net-regex) link. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for noticing.</sub>

Comment: In .NET regex, when one wants to match ASCII digits, it [is safer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) to use `[0-9]`. Your pattern [also matches](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b3%7d%5ba-zA-Z%5d%24&i=%e0%b1%a6%e1%a7%97%e0%b5%adA) `string Case1 = "౦᧗൭A";`. So, "*`\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`*" is not correct in .NET regex context.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for noticing. I added a disclaimer.