# How can I modify this regex to support multiple alternatives?

Tags: c#, regex

im a newbie at constructing regex.

I have this working regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\d]+-)*[a-zA-Z0-9\d]+$
```

Example:

```
-test : false 
test- : false
te--st : false
test : true
test-test : true 
te-st-t : true
```

I would like to add support for _ (underscores), so the above example replaced - to _ is the same result, but can only be one option only.

Example:

```
te-st_test : false
te_st_test : true
```

The solutions I tried:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9\d]+(-|_))*[a-zA-Z0-9\d]+$

^(([a-zA-Z0-9\d]+-)|([a-zA-Z0-9\d]+_))*[a-zA-Z0-9\d]+$
```

Bad result:

```
te_st-test : true
```

I would like to have this result:

```
-test : false
test- : false
--test : false
__test : false
test-- : false
test__ : false
-_test : false
test-_ : false
test--test : false
test__test : false
test-_test : false
te-st_test : false
te-st : true
te_st : true
te_st_test : true
te-st-test : true
test : true
```

**Thanks & have a nice day!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may capture the first delimiter  (if any) and then use a backreference to that value in the repeated non-capturing group:

```cs
^[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=([-_])?)(?:\1[a-zA-Z\d]+)*$
\A[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=([-_])?)(?:\1[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zIdOjx/2/).

**Note**: when validating strings, I'd rather use `\A` (start of string) and `\z` (the very end of string) anchors rather than `^`/`$`.
Also, if you are worried about [matching all Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-is-less-efficient-than-0-9) (e.g. `३৫৬૦૧௮೪൮໘`) with `\d` you need to pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option when compiling the regex object, or replace `\d` with `0-9` inside the character class.

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?=([-_])?)` - a positive lookahead that captures into Group 1 the next char that is an optional `-` or `_`
- `(?:\1[a-zA-Z\d]+)*` - zero or more sequences of Group 1 value and one or more letters or digits
- `\z` - the very end of string.

In C#, you can declare it as

```cs
var Pattern = new Regex(@"\A[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=([-_])?)(?:\1[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\z");
// Or,
var Pattern = new Regex(@"\A[a-zA-Z\d]+(?=([-_])?)(?:\1[a-zA-Z\d]+)*\z", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```