# Python regex pattern matching with ranges and whitespaces

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to match strings that would have a pattern of:

- two uppercase Latin letters
- two digits
- two uppercase Latin letters
- four digits
- ex: MH 45 LE 4098

There can be optional whitespaces between the first three and they need to be limited to these numbers of characters. I was trying to group them and set a limit on the characters, but I am not matching any strings that fall within the define parameters. I had attempted building a set like so `template = '[A-Z{2}0-9{2,4}]'`, but was still receiving errors when the last digits had exceeded 4.

```
template = '(A-Z{2})\s?(\d{2})\s?(A-Z{2})\s?(\d{4})'
```

This was the other attempt when I tried being more verbose, but then couldn't match anything.

Comment: No, sorry. I just wrote an example. I should have been clearer in my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close; need to put a square brackets around `A-Z` to let `{2}` affect the whole range instead of only `Z`. As it stands it literally matches `A-ZZ`.

So

```py
template = "[A-Z]{2}\s?(\d{2})\s?([A-Z]{2})\s?(\d{4})"
```

should do. We use `[` instead of `(` to imply a *range* of letters. If we put `(`, it would try to match `A-ZA-Z` i.e. literally `A-Z` two times.

You can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/1Y4HuE/1) and you can change them to `(` or omit them to see the effect in the demo.

Comment: That did work! Ah, that makes sense. Thank you for that resource too! I'm going to go check it out now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the regex you are looking for:

```
[A-Z]{2}\s?[0-9]{2}\s?[A-Z]{2}\s?[0-9]{4}
```

Note that it allows multiple whitespace characters.

Comment: Would it be better to indicate numbers by `\d` instead of `[0-9]` ?

Comment: I thought there is no difference, but your comment made me look into this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9. Apparently, `\d` would capture any unicode digits.

Comment: Would there be a way to limit the whitespace to one character instead of allowing multiple?

Comment: Just that `\d` looks more succinct and commonly gives cleaner regex especially when the regex is long.

Comment: @NotPretendingToBeSomebodyElse sure, a `?` instead of a `*` will do the job. Please see the edited answer.