# How to replace each digit in a string with a different character?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to get a string, for example, "e1e2e3" to have each digit replaced with a different character, which in this case would be a random number. Whereas instead of e1e2e3, it could be something like e5e9e1 because each number is replaced with a random one.

I tried

```
string txt = textBox1.Text;
Regex digits = new Regex(@"\d", RegexOptions.None);
Random rand = new Random();
txt = digits.Replace(txt, rand.Next(0, 9).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(txt);
```

The problem is, every single number is replaced with the same random number. "e1e2e3" would then be something like "e2e2e2" where each number is the same.

Comment: Do you want all 1's to be replaced with the same random digit or do you want them to be different?

Comment: You would need to use the overload of `Replace` that takes a [`MatchEvaluator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you can use the [callback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchEvaluator_) of Regex.Replace to create a random value for each replacement, instead of using a single random value.

If you just want to match digits 0-9 you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` as the latter could match [all Unicode digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9)

```
string txt = textBox1.Text;
Regex digits = new Regex(@"\d", RegexOptions.None);
Random rand = new Random();
txt = digits.Replace(txt, match => rand.Next(0, 9).ToString());
MessageBox.Show(txt);
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Coo9AR)

Answer (score 2):

approach without `RegEx`

```
string txt = "e1e2e3";           
Random rand = new Random();
string res = string.Concat(txt.Select(x => char.IsDigit(x)?(char)('0'+rand.Next(0, 9)):x));
```

---

Side note to the second `int` parameter of [`Next(int,int)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-5.0)

> The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must be greater than or equal to minValue.

if you want values between `0` and `9`, you should use `Next(0, 10)`