# Regex to match 7 same digits in a number regardless of position

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match an 8 digit number. Currently, I have the following regex but It is failing in some cases.

```
(\d+)\1{6}
```

It matches only when a number is different at the end such as 44444445 or 54444444. However, I am looking to match cases where at least 7 digits are the same regardless of their position.
It is failing in cases like

```
44454444
44544444
44444544
```

What modification is needed here?

Comment: why would you want to do that by regex. Performance would be terrible because it'll need to backtrack a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to use this in a performance-sensitive location, but **you can use a capture reference to achieve this.**

The Regex you need is as follows:

```
(\d)(?:.*?\1){6}
```

**Breaking it down:**

- `(\d)` Capture group of any single digit
- `.*?` means match any character, zero or more times, lazily
- `\1` means match the first capture group
- We enclose that in a non-capturing group `{?:`
- And add a quantifier `{6}` to match six times

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the digits before matching

```
string input = "44444445 54444444 44454444 44544444 44444544";
string[] numbers = input.Split(' ');
foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    number = String.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c));
    if (Regex.IsMatch(number, @"(\d+)\1{6}"))
        // do something
}
```

Still not a good idea to use regex for this though

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you tried `(\d+)\1{6}` matches 6 of the same digits in a row. If you want to stretch the match over multiple same digits, you have to match optional digits in between.

Note that in .NET `\d` matches [more digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621738/d-less-efficient-than-0-9) than 0-9 only.

If you want to match only digits 0-9 using C# without matching other characters in between the digits:

```
([0-9])(?:[0-9]*?\1){6}
```

The pattern matches:

- `([0-9])` Capture **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[0-9]*?\1` Match optional digits 0-9 and a backreference to group 1
- `){6}` Close non capture group and repeat 6 times

See a [.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b0-9%5d%29%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d*%3f%5c1%29%7b6%7d&i=44444445%0d%0a54444444.+%0d%0a44454444+%0d%0a44544444%0d%0a44444544%0d%0a444445449%0d%0a444445%0d%0a1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+%0d%0a%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3)

---

If you want to match only 8 digits, you can use a positive lookahead `(?=` to assert 8 digits and word boundaries `\b`

```
\b(?=\d{8}\b)[0-9]*([0-9])(?:[0-9]*?\1){6}\d*\b
```

See another [.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3d%5cd%7b8%7d%5cb%29%5b0-9%5d*%28%5b0-9%5d%29%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d*%3f%5c1%29%7b6%7d%5cd*%5cb&i=44444445%0d%0a54444444.+%0d%0a44454444+%0d%0a44544444%0d%0a44444544%0d%0a444445449%0d%0a444445%0d%0a1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+1+test+%0d%0a%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3%d9%a3)