# Regular expression for SSN without all consecutive numbers

Tags: regex

I'm working on a regular expression for SSN with the rules below.  I have successfully applied all matching rules except #7. Can someone help alter this expression to include the last rule, #7:

```
^((?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}-(?!00)[0-9]{2}-(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$|(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}(?!00)[0-9]{2}(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$)
```

1. Hyphens should be optional (this is handled above by using 2 expressions with an OR
2. Cannot begin with 000
3. Cannot begin with 666
4. Cannot begin with 900-999
5. Middle digits cannot be 00
6. Last four digits cannot 0000
7. **Cannot be all the same numbers ex: 111-11-1111 or 111111111**

Comment: Add `(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)*\D*$)` after `^`.

Comment: BTW, does hyphens optional mean each hyphen is optional so `123-456789` is OK, or does it mean the pair of hyphens are optional, so they are either both there or both absent?

Comment: If your issue is not solved, please let us know what, and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following negative look ahead anchored to start:

```
^(?!(.)(\1|-)+$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/x3FlI5ZBPNcZsI).

This captures the first character then asserts the rest of the input is not made of that captured char or hyphen.

The whole regex can be shortened to:

```
^(?!(.)(\1|-)+$)(?!000|666|9..)(?!...-?00)(?!.*0000$)\d{3}(-?)\d\d\3\d{4}$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/3oDUcH7EbP9P8y).

The main trick to not having to repeat the regex both with and without the hyphens was to *capture* the optional hyphen (as group 3), then use a back reference `\3` to the capture in the next position, so are either both there or both absent.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's shorten the pattern as it contains two next-to identical alternatives, one matching SSN with hyphens, and the other matching the SSN numbers without hyphens. Instead of `^(x-y-z$|xyz$)` pattern, you can use a `^x(-?)y\1z$` pattern, so your regex can get reduced to `^(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}(-?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\1(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMCwET/1) here.

To make a pattern never match a string that contains only identical digits, you may add the following negative lookahead right after `^`:

```
(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)*\D*$)
```

It fails the match if there are

- `\D*` - zero or more non-digits
- `(\d)` - a digit (captured in Group 1)
- `(?:\D*\1)*` - zero or more occurrences of any zero or more non-digits and then then same digit as in Group 1, and then
- `\D*$` - zero or more non-digits till the end of string.

Now, since I suggested shortening the regex to the pattern with backreference(s), you will have to adjust the backreferences after adding this lookahead.

So, your **solution looks like**

```
^(?!\D*(\d)(?:\D*\1)*\D*$)(?!000|666)[0-8]\d{2}(-?)(?!00)\d{2}\2(?!0000)\d{4}$
^(?![^0-9]*([0-9])(?:[^0-9]*\1)*[^0-9]*$)(?!000|666)[0-8][0-9]{2}(-?)(?!00)[0-9]{2}\2(?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```

Note the `\1` in the pattern without the lookahead turned into `\2` as `(-?)` became Group 2.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/eMCwET/2).

Note also that [in some regex flavors `\d` is not equal to `[0-9]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778/3832970).