# Check if string ends with several digits after some specific char in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have some list that is holding several strings, for example:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>()
        {
            "REGISTER_OPTION_P2", "REGISTER_OPTION_P27", "REGISTER_OPTION_P254","REGISTER_OPTION_NOFW", "POWER_OPTION_P45JW"
        };
```

I Want to filter all the strings that are ending with the `_P*`where `*` is several digits only and not non-digits.

The result for the above will hold the following:

```
"REGISTER_OPTION_P2", "REGISTER_OPTION_P27", "REGISTER_OPTION_P254"
```

I know there is `char.IsDigit()` but it operates only on 1 digit. My case is multiple digits.

Any option to make it?

Comment: Have you explored regular expressions? Is there a maximum and minimum number of digits after the P? Will the P always be after the last underscore?

Comment: @gunr2171 No min or max

Comment: No minimum, so there could be 0 digits?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes could be 0

Comment: Yes P will be always after underscore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var lst = new[] {"REGISTER_OPTION_P2", "REGISTER_OPTION_P27", "REGISTER_OPTION_P254","REGISTER_OPTION_NOFW", "POWER_OPTION_P45JW"};
var pattern = @"_P[0-9]*$";
var result = lst.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft));
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
REGISTER_OPTION_P2
REGISTER_OPTION_P27
REGISTER_OPTION_P254
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/egQ4DN).

*Details*:

- `_P` - a fixed string
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note the use of `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` that greatly enhances matching at the end of the string.

Comment: though 0-9 aren't the only digits in this world maybe consider `\d` instead (OP didn't spedify the limitation to only 0-9)

Comment: @RandRandom Following the [`\d` less efficient than \[0-9\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/3832970), I tend to use explicit digit patterns when it comes to ASCII digits (as shown in the examples). If any Unicode digits like `۱`, `௫` or `৫` can appear after `_P`, yes, `\d*` would be best.

Answer (score 2):

So the regex expression that will catch that is

```
P(\d+$)
```

\d stands for digit, + is more than 1, $ is the end of the string, and () specifies that it should be captured. C# should have a findAll function in regex.

One tool that is really helpful for me (because I'm not great at regex) is

https://www.autoregex.xyz/

Comment: Might want to include the P in the pattern. This also does not work with 0 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `String.Replace()` function

```
"REGISTER_OPTION_P42".Replace("REGISTER_OPTION_P",string.Empty) = "42"
```

or use the `String.Substring()` function

```
"REGISTER_OPTION_P42".Substring(17) = "42"
```

and then use `.All( (c)=>char.IsDigit(c) )` to check that all remaining characters are digits.

---

sample code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<string>(new string[] { "REGISTER_OPTION_P23", "REGISTER_OPTION_P823", "REGISTER_OPTION_P1Q6", "REGISTER_OPTION_P5" });

    var filtered = list.Where((s) => s.Replace("REGISTER_OPTION_P", string.Empty).All((c)=>char.IsDigit(c))).ToList();

    foreach (var item in filtered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    //REGISTER_OPTION_P23
    //REGISTER_OPTION_P823
    //REGISTER_OPTION_P5
}
```

Comment: Clever solution, though there's the obvious downside that this will only work with a fixed prefix. If that works for the OP, great.

Comment: `int.TryParse` has some downsides: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xRMVCf

Comment: @RandRandom - I see that, and I updated the answer to use `.All((c)=>char.IsDigit(c))` for the checking.