# Cannot access non-static method 'IsMatch' in static context

Tags: c#, regex, static-methods

I am not able to figure out the simple compile error I am getting on `Regex.Match` method.

The error says

> Cannot access non-static method 'IsMatch' in static context

[image]

The error text is confusing in itself because the method I am calling is the static method of the `Regex` class while the error says that I cannot access `non-static` method in statc context.

My context is also not `static` because the method in which I have calling `Regex.IsMatch` function is a non-static method, even the class is also non static.

The error is confusing!

It works when I replace the call with the Regex class' instance call like this

`new Regex(@"/^(?:2[89]|[3-9]\d)\d{6,}$/").IsMatch(@"/^(?:2[89]|[3-9]\d)\d{6,}$/")`

But I am totally confused of why can't I call the static method of the class!

Comment: the `IsMatch` with 1 string parameter is not static  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string) but the one with 2 is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string-system-string)

Comment: "[_Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)"

Answer (score 3):

There is no `static` method `IsMatch` accepting only one parameter.

[`IsMatch(string input, string pattern)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string-system-string)) is `static`, but [`IsMatch(string input)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string)) is not and needs to be called on an instance that already has been given a pattern (because, thinking about it, what pattern would be used if this method was `static` and we only provide an input string to it?)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#overloads) is where you can find all available overloads.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an input string to the [`Regex.IsMatch` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string-system-string)).

However, you also need to amend the regex and remove the leading and trailing slashes that you must be using as regex delimiter chars. Those slashes are treated as part of a pattern and will prevent your regex from matching any string. Remember that regular expressions are defined with string literals (`"..."`) in C#, not with regex literals (`/.../`).

So you need to use

```cs
Regex.IsMatch(item.HSCode, @"^(?:2[89]|[3-9]\d)\d{6,}$")
```

Also, consider using `[0-9]` instead of `\d` if you only expect ASCII digits in the input, see [\d less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/3832970).