# How to match fixed length string with quantifiers

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings like this:

- 123456-000**1**
- 123456-00**12**
- 123456-0**123**

How to match with next conditions:

- chars count after - should be 4
- zeros count variable - from 1 to 3

I found `^\d{6}-0+([1-9]+)$` pattern but it matches for 123456-001 or 123456-00001.

Comment: Looking for `\d{6}-0{1,3}\d{1,3}`? This will match strings with six digits before the hyphen, followed by a hyphen, then 1 to 3 zeros, and 1 to 3 digits, totaling four characters after the hyphen.

Comment: @SonerGönül, the regex you suggest will match `"123456789-000000012345678"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\d{6}-(?=\d{4}$)0+([1-9]\d*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/18s0n8/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?=\d{4}$)` - from this position and to the end of string, there must be four digits
- `0+` - one or more zeros
- `([1-9]\d*)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit and then any zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string (use `\z` if you need the very end of string).

Note:

- `(?=\d{4}$)` is the positive lookahead that enforces the four digit only rule
- `0+` - makes a zero required (so one or more zeros is enforced)
- `([1-9]\d*)` captures any non-zero digit and then any digits including zeros (`0100` will now get matched, too.)

Also, consider checking `\d` vs. `[0-9]` at [\d less efficient than [0-9]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/3832970).